# Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?

Tags: pdf, compiling, jobname

I'd like to be able to create a TeX file that will output multiple PDF files with one compilation.  I'm not even sure if this is possible.  Here is the setup:

I am writing dozens of cover letters for job applications, and wish for them to all look "personalized".  So I defined a function which calls multiple variables, such as the address, name of the institution, open position, etc., and outputs a "personalized" cover letter for each function call.  The problem is that compilation of the TeX file outputs just one file.  Since I will be submitting all of these files online eventually, I would like each letter to be in its own file.  Is there a way to do this at the TeX level?

Comment: Another use for this kind of thing would be to have one compile command output a beamer slides pdf and a handout pdf...

Comment: What operating system are you on? A simple batch file or script could be made to do what you want easily enough.

Comment: probably easier to write a makefile/script that regex's the necessary "personalized" parts then generates the file and compiles it to PDF.

Comment: I use the plain `letter` class and [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Comment: This isn't TeX, so I'm not going to make it an answer, but I think using some of scripting language that does a find and replace for you then runs LaTeX on each of the resulting would be simpler. Python, perl, awk, sed, bash... Are you familiar with any of those? A simple linux script to do that would not be hard.

Comment: Just another answer for Windows users: [How to compile a single TeX input file to produce multiple identical PDF outputs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74260/9467)

Comment: I wish this were possible, since it will make compilation faster if properly used. But apparently it is not. The closest thing I saw is in http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/ that in order to generate multiple small rendered TeX pictures, it creates a large file with a picture per page and then it splits or reads each page separately. All this internally behind the scenes.

Comment: This is also useful for sending your phdthesis.pdf through email with size limitations.

Comment: Also usefull for creating one document with only assignments and another which includes the answers in one run.

Comment: Probably not what OP is looking for, but in the special case if the multiple PDF files has identical content there's a [LuaTeX solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472944/compile-to-pdf-file-with-different-name-than-the-source/).

Comment: My use case is to announce a talk at several venues in several languages. The build should run on all 3 major desktop operating systems without external dependencies like having a scripting language like Perl installed.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

How do you store this information? You could just have one info-file for each letter

```
% letter1.adr
\def\toname{Foo}
```

and

```
% letter2.adr
\def\toname{Bar}
```

and then have a main file

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[addrfield]{scrlttr2}
\input \jobname.adr

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{\toname}
\opening{Dear \toname, }
 A nice letter.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Then you can compile all letters from the command line with something like

```
for %i in (*.adr) do pdflatex -jobname=%i main.tex
```

The [koma bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) also provides tools for more sophisticated address files.

Comment: I've been using essentially this trick for years, to ensure that items charged on invoices match up with the work specified in contracts.

Comment: I do the same except I use a makefile for managing the dependencies and rebuilds.

Comment: This was just what I was looking for; thanks!

Answer (score 55):

Yes it is possible if you enable `\write18` (e.g. `pdflatex --shell-escape` with MiKTeX). Then you can call `pdflatex` again inside your document. An example (the code is not from me). It will generate three documents `\jobname1`-`\jobname3`:

## Case insensitive operating systems (e.g. Windows/MacOS)

```
\documentclass{article}

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
  \immediate\write18{%
    pdfLaTeX --jobname="\jobname1"
    \gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname
  }%
  \immediate\write18{%
    pdfLaTeX --jobname="\jobname2"
    \gdef\string\conditionmacro{2}\string\input\space\jobname
  }%
  \immediate\write18{%
    pdfLaTeX --jobname="\jobname3"
    \gdef\string\conditionmacro{3}\string\input\space\jobname
  }%
  \expandafter\stop
\fi

\begin{document}
\ifnum\conditionmacro=1 Condition is 1\fi
\ifnum\conditionmacro=2 Condition is 2\fi
\ifnum\conditionmacro=3 Condition is 3\fi

\verb|\conditionmacro| is \texttt{\meaning\conditionmacro}.
\end{document}
```

## Case sensitive operating systems (e.g. Linux)

As noted in Martin Heller's comment you need to change this code for case sensitive operating systems to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
  \immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname1"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname2"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{2}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname3"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{3}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \expandafter\stop
\fi

\begin{document}

\ifnum\conditionmacro=1 Condition is 1\fi 

\ifnum\conditionmacro=2 Condition is 2\fi

\ifnum\conditionmacro=3 Condition is 3\fi

\verb|\conditionmacro| is \texttt{\meaning\conditionmacro}.

\end{document}
```

### Edit for lualatex

in newer luatex version \write18 has no special meaning anymore and can't be used like this. You then need the shellesc package which overloads `\write`. It also offers a `\ShellEscape` which can be used (also with pdflatex) instead of the primitive commands. The example looks then like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
  \ShellEscape{%
    lualatex --jobname="\jobname1"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \ShellEscape{%
    lualatex --jobname="\jobname2"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{2}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \ShellEscape{%
    lualatex --jobname="\jobname3"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{3}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \expandafter\stop
\fi

\begin{document}

\ifnum\conditionmacro=1 Condition is 1\fi

\ifnum\conditionmacro=2 Condition is 2\fi

\ifnum\conditionmacro=3 Condition is 3\fi

\verb|\conditionmacro| is \texttt{\meaning\conditionmacro}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. On case sensitive systems you need to use lowercase for the call to `pdflatex`. I also had to add quotes around the `\gdef...`.

Comment: I know it's old but --- thanks. I use to prepare multiple versions of tests and exams and this helps me a lot. Now I will try to search how to make this work with `latexmk`....

Comment: while this is an interesting, surprising, and working solution, it works essentially like an external script calling n different, precompiled tex sources. specifically, the overhead of getting LaTeX up and running—load all the packages needed—is present for each single pdf produced. that means a solution which first produces a multiple-page pdf that is then split into single pages *might* be more performant.

Comment: @flow: This one starts multiple instances that will run in parallell, right? For larger documents I am guessing the overhead of starting up is much smaller than the actual work of compiling so on todays multitasking monster machines I am guessing this might in fact instead be faster. At least for larger projects... yes / no?

Comment: It generates `main1` `main2` main3`. Is there a solution to name the output pdfs?

Comment: @CroCo Sure, change `\jobname1`, `\jobname2` etc to whatever you want.

Comment: @jonalv I don't think it will run them in parallel. You could probably change the code to do that, but I doubt this code would do so. (Might be OS dependent, though, or depend on the shell.)

Comment: @Charlie: You should I know why your document doesn't compile? Make a sensible problem description with an example and ask a new question.

Answer (score 30):

The answer is no, TeX outputs one PDF file.

I'd use a tool to split the PDF files afterwards. [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/) (TeX) [pdfsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/), and [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) should do the trick.

Comment: If have found `pdftk` to be cumbersome if you want to split a PDF into k-page chunks for k>1. So, naturally, I wrote [a script](https://github.com/akerbos/scripts/blob/master/pdfsplitk) to do it more conveniently.

Comment: Pdfsam (which is in Debian's depot) and its "split by bookmark level" option is really nice. Good job, simple to use, perfect.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but here is an alternative approach, based on an idea from [Automatically create two PDF output files from one tex file [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/automatically-create-two-pdf-output-files-from-one-tex-file)

The idea is to write at begin of each chapter some commands (including the page numbers where to split the pdf) in a batch-file and after LaTex has finished, run the script to split the pdf into multiple files (using pdftk).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pageslts} %  theCurrentPage
\usepackage{calc} % theCurrentPage+1
\usepackage{blindtext} % Lorem ipsum dolor ...

\newcounter{FirstPage} % counter, for first page number
\setcounter{FirstPage}{1} % Set FirstPage to page 1

\newwrite\BatchFile% Batch-Datei
\immediate\openout\BatchFile=BatchFile.txt% *.bat don't work

\newcommand{\Split}[1]{%
\immediate\write\BatchFile{pdftk.exe\space \jobname.pdf\space cat \theFirstPage -\theCurrentPage\space output\space \jobname-#1.pdf dont_ask}% 
\setcounter{FirstPage}{\theCurrentPage+1}% set FirstPage to new first page
}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % for pageslts

\chapter{One}

\Blindtext 

\Split{C1} % Split for Chapter 1  
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{Two}

\Blindtext\Blindtext

\Split{C2} % Split for Chapter 2
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{Three}
\setcounter{page}{1} % Chapter 3 with new page numbers

\Blindtext \Blindtext \blindtext 

\Split{C3} % Split for Chapter 3
%==========================
\immediate\write\BatchFile{exit}% 
\immediate\closeout\BatchFile% 
\immediate\write18{cmd /c move BatchFile.txt BatchFile.bat} % rename Batch File
\end{document}
```

I know the solution can be improved, for example merge the \Split with the \chapter command or do the stuff at the end automatically.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I'm amused that you've linked to a post that is closed as a duplicate of this question.  But more importantly, I think this will only work if you're splitting chapters or similar documents.  If you want to have different `\documentclass`, for example, this approach won't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can do as Patrick says, or you can generate TeX files from a script language (say, Perl + Template Toolkit) and then use environment variables to pass the parameters.

E.g. on Linux with bash, you can do
`$ PARAM1=VALUE1 PARAM2=VALUE2 perl ./compile.pl`

Comment: +1 for Perl + TT (http://search.cpan.org/~abw/Template-Toolkit-2.22/lib/Template.pm), but why pass parameters on env variables? In the script that will do the compiling just have a hash of the data needed and foreach of the keys do a replace/compile

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use something along the lines of awk or sed to do a replacement?

Comment: @Canageek, it's just my prejudice against editing the code when I can use inputs :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can make a single .tex file produce multiple .PDFs, however you could create some very simple .tex files (one per PDF you want to create), which simply set up a few macros (your personalised variables) and then `\input` (or `\include`) the common .tex file.

Running `pdflatex` (or whatever *TeX-to-xxx* converter/compiler you like best) on each of the small files will produce all your PDFs.

(Probably worth writing a little script to compile each one if the differing elements are more than very simple macro replacements)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on my comment to Alexei,
If you make a file test.tex with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello [% name %]

\end{document}
```

and a test.pl with:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Template;

my $tt = Template->new(); 

my @names = ('john','sally');
my $infile = 'test.tex';

foreach my $name (@names) {
  my %data;
  my $outname = $name . 'tex';
  $data{'name'} = $name;
  $tt->process($infile,\%data, $outname);
  system("latexmk -pdf $outname");
  system("latexmk -c");
}
```

when you execute test.pl you should get a john.tex and a john.pdf, etc in the same folder. Its a simple example but I'm sure you can extend it to what you need. PS if you don't know latexmk, check it out!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with the letter options in KOMA script, it's briefly in the manual although I haven't personally experimented with it.

Answer (score 1):

Since cover letter usually does not exceed 1 page, it is possible to extract given range of pages from Adobe Acrobat using **Tools** | **Pages** | **Extract** | **Extract Pages As Separate Files**.