# How to influence the name of the pdf file created with pdfLaTeX (from within the source code)?

Tags: external-files, jobname

I have a source file called `2011-05-27_Myfilename.tex` and I'd like to create a PDF file from it called only `Myfilename.pdf`.

Can this be configured from within the .tex file itself?

(It seems to be possible with

```
pdflatex -jobname=Myfilename.tex 2011-05-27_Myfilename.tex
```

However, as many different files are concerned, It would be easier to have an option like `output=Myfilename` in the LaTeX source code.)

Comment: I'm used to making `Makefile` scripts to generate my PDFs. If that is your case, too, it's easy to enough to either rename the `.tex` or the `.pdf` in the process.

Comment: @Raphink: Thanks, that `Makefile` approach sounds like a good workaround, however I did not use it yet. As I'm using GUI editors it is quite easy to use the keyboard shortcut to run pdflatex.

Comment: If you have a source file called `<date>_myfilename.tex`, that probably means you aren't using a version control system. I _highly_ recommend you take a few minutes to learn one such as [git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), it will make your life easier and better in the long run. Once you get the hang of it you'll never go back to manually saving incremental copies of a file.

Comment: @Caleb: thank you, good point. I was asking that question 7 years ago, so I don't remember the circumstances exactly, but I have been using a VCS for years now and you're right, it is great and very helpful. (However it is still sometimes difficult for me as a non-programmer to understand the details of it.)

Comment: There is also [shell escape - copy finalised PDF to new directory - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210306/copy-finalised-pdf-to-new-directory/705582#705582) / [macros - Compile to PDF file with different name than the source - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472944/compile-to-pdf-file-with-different-name-than-the-source?noredirect=1&lq=1) which can give a solution as long as you use LuaLaTeX and don't mind the old file linger .

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot alter the output name from within the LaTeX source: the `\jobname` primitive can be read but not altered. You can arrange two-file solutions which allow one LaTeX file to 'call' another, but I am not sure that will answer your problem here.

Comment: Just found this question and I have one more remark: obviously, you *can* do `\def\jobname{whatever}`, and if you do it early enough, it will affect the names of the .aux, .toc etc. files - but not the pdf.

Comment: Can you, please, add details to the "two-file solution"? How do I "call" another tex file from another one?

Comment: For solutions to output multiple files, refer to a [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5265/134641).

Answer (score 29):

You can specify additional parameters (like `jobname`) at the very beginning of your main file (even before `\documentclass`):

```
%& -job-name=newfilenameialwayswanted
```

It slightly depends on your compiler but it should work.

An additional comment: If you use an IDE, this may cause troubles for file opening hotkeys (the file they will try to open will not be there), in this case, you can look for an option like "output profile" (TeXnicCenter name) - you can also change the filename this way.

So there're no totally convenient ways to change your output filename from source, but it is possible.

Comment: These parameters **must** be at the first line(s) of the file for them to work. In case anyone else is having problems with that.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: does the % not out comment the code after? I use TexStudio and when I use % it gets immediately out commented. So I don't know how it should work

Comment: Yes, a special kind of comment. Like #!/bin/bash is a comment on top of shell scripts.

Comment: This does not work for me (I think with TeX Live on Windows, using VS Code and a LaTeX extension there, so not sure where exactly the problem happens).

Comment: @clel It could be that VSCode might be adding other things to your file at the top... check whether it works or not without VSCODE from command line...
But I really don't know. Haven't used tex for ages.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me either using PDFLaTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 on Linux.

Answer (score 6):

You can do as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}
\foreach \outputfilename in {a,b,c}{\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\outputfilename\space template}}
\begin{document}
The files we created automatically are:

\foreach \outputfilename in {a,b,c}{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=2]{\outputfilename}}\endgraf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this didn't work for me as is. I compiled with ``pdflatex`` Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT you need to run `pdflatex` with the `--shell-escape` flag

Comment: Got it, thanks Ahlqvist! (on texstudio, I just added this at the top of the document: ``% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]``).

Comment: beware: if you are writing the list of filenames over several lines, end each line with a ``%`` to make sure you gobble up empty spaces. In my implementation ``\includegraphics``  was looking for ``a .pdf`` (with a space before the dot) and couldn't find it...

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but my file doesn't run even when entering `!TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]` in the first line. Error: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` Without the line, my error is `! LaTeX Error: File `a' not found.`

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5265/46718 by @ulrike-fischer , the following code do the job for me for me when compiling with the `--shell-escape` option:

```
\def\myjobname{Myfilename}

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
  \immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\myjobname"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \expandafter\stop
\fi
```

*(this may need improvements since I'm not sure I understand all subtleties)*

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly answering the OP's question, and looking at the accepted answer that seems to indicate a possibility via a multi-file solution I wanted to provide exactly such a multi-file solution alternative of managing such issues. If one is using [VimTeX](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/), it is quite easy to create differently named `pdf` files as output from the compilation process workflow of the same `.tex` file.

[Here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/2588) is an example provided the author of that plugin.

Roughly, have an outer `student.tex` and `professor.tex` (with possibly differently defined variables/commands/macros thereby controlling what gets typeset how). Both of these files get to `\input{main.tex}` the same file -- all three files in the same folder.

Once `student.tex` and `professor.tex` are setup, there is little to no need to keep updating them. All work can now happen in `main.tex`.

On opening `main.tex`, in Vim, the plugin automatically asks the user to specify which the calling file is -- `student.tex` or `professor.tex`. On making the choice, and on issuing the equivalent of the compile command [`\ll` in VimTeX], compilation occurs and based on the choice made, the output is `student.pdf` or `professor.pdf`.

See example (provided by the author of the plugin) below:

[image]

```
% main.tex
\begin{document}
Hello World! \person
\end{document}

% professor.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\person}{from professor}
\input{main.tex}

% student.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\person}{from student}
\input{main.tex}
```