# Is it possible to change jobname from within the input file?

Tags: write-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to influence the name of the pdf file created with pdfLaTeX (from within the source code)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the)

I have a template as follows.

```
% template.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{0pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\begin{document}
\InputIfFileExists{\InputFileName}{%
    % if it is compiled with latex.exe, it will produce DVI output with \InputFileName as its name.
    % if it is compiled with pdflatex.exe or xelatex.exe, it will produce PDF output with \InputFileName as its name.
}{%
    % notify error!
}   
\end{document}
```

If I execute either `TeXDviPsPdf.bat subfile` or `TeXPdf.bat subfile` in the DOS prompt,

```
rem TeXDviPsPdf.bat takes a file name without extension
latex "\def\InputFileName{%1}\input{template}"
dvips %1.dvi
ps2pdf %1.ps
acrord32 %1.pdf
```

```
rem TeXPdf.bat takes a file name without extension
xelatex "\def\InputFileName{%1}\input{template}"
acrord32 %1.pdf
```

where the `subfile.tex` contains code as follows

```
% subfile.tex
\input{pstricks}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
\psframe(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
```

I will obtain `subfile.pdf` rather than `template.pdf`.

Is it possible to produce a DVI or PDF output with a name specified in the TeX input file?

Note: I can actually rename it in the batch files, but I want to know whether it is possible to be done internally.

Comment: What's the sense of `\InputIfFileExists{\input{...}}{}`? The command has *three* arguments and the first should be a file name. Please, correct the example.

Comment: +1 @egreg: Thanks for checking the code. It has been corrected.

Comment: It's still wrong: why input the file twice? The file *is* input if it exists; the second argument contains code to be executed before inputting the file.

Comment: @egreg: DONE. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From within latex is not possible, try

```
latex --jobname=%1 "\def\InputFileName{%1}\input{template}"
```

Comment: +1 but I want to change it internally.

Comment: from within latex is not possible