# Automatically create two PDF output files from one tex file

Tags: pdftex, compiling, jobname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files)

Let's say I have a tex file `foo.tex`. Now, I want to achieve that pdflatex does not only create a file `foo.pdf` but simultaneously a file `fooxy.pdf` which is identical (!) to `foo.pdf`. Is there a simple solution to this problem?

PS:

- Yes, I could just do this by copying and renaming the file in the file manager. But I want to have an automatic solution.
- No, I am not crazy. Please don't ask me *why* I want to do this.

Comment: this would be very easy with a `perl` or `bash` script; but as detailed in [how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the) it is not possible to influence the name of `\jobname.pdf` from within the `.tex` file

Comment: `pdflatex foo.tex && cp foo.pdf fooxy.pdf`

Comment: @N.N. That's pratcically what I meant with doing it in the file manager ...

Comment: @ Peter Grill: Well, I did take notice of that post but I am not sure whether it really is a duplicate ... My case is much simpler since I just want to produce two identical copies of the same file. I thought there might possibly be a simple solution for *that*. The accepted answer in the other post would of course work here but it means having two main files. I wwas wondering whether it is possible with just one main file.

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't agree that this is a duplicate. I'm sure that some answers for this question need not to work for the other one, and there is no answer in the other one that would satisfy this one.

Comment: @tohecz: Wouldn't Ulrike Fischer's answer work here? But even if there is not an existing answer that solves this problem, I think that the answers should be added to the other question.

Comment: See my answer. It has been tested and works very well!

Comment: @Ipdbw: I know you said not to ask why you need this, but it is kind of intriguing...

Comment: As per http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/closing-questions-as-exact-duplications-best-practice, I think we should wait a bit before closing as a dupe. (I'm not certain it is, anyway, but that's a separate point.)

Comment: What does the `!` mean in your "identical (!)"? Should they be 100% identical including the creation date and time?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't generate identical bitwise level output files from `pdflatex`, unless a modification in the program source code to flush data to two output streams at the same time. Even by running `pdflatex` on the same `.tex` file will produce different checksums every time. The only way to garantee a 1:1 copy is, well, by copying the target `.pdf` file.

Comment: With identical I only mean identical in content and appearance. Creation date and time need to be the same!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of three ways to approach this:

### &&

You could just add a copy command after `pdflatex` as in the following:

```bsh
pdflatex foo.tex && cp foo.pdf fooxy.pdf
```

The does everything you want in one line and it is a simple solution.

### Make

You could make it slightly more sophisticated by making a Makefile such as the following:

```bsh
namebase = foo
nameaddon = xy
tex = pdflatex          # Might wanna set this to latexmk

.PHONY : all
all : $(namebase)$(nameaddon).pdf

$(namebase)$(nameaddon).pdf : $(namebase).pdf
    cp $< $@

$(namebase).pdf : $(namebase).tex
    $(tex) $<
```

This gives you more flexibility when it comes to naming file and it does not compile or copy unless it is needed. You only have to issue

```bsh
make all
```

and `make` decides what needs to be done.

### tee

This does **not** work but was the first approach I came to think about. The command `tee` reads from standard input and writes to standard output and the files given as arguments. If `pdflatex` would write the pdf to standard output you could have used

```bsh
pdflatex foo.tex | tee foo.pdf fooxy.pdf > /dev/null
```

but as `pdflatex` [does not](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5230/5701) this approach fails.

Answer (score 5):

### Only for Microsoft Windows users.

It has been properly tested in my daily jobs and works.

```
rem this file name is pdflatexdup.bat

rem first arg specifies the master input filename without extension
rem remaining args specifies a list of duplicate filenames

rem remove the previously created master PDF
if exist "%~1.pdf" del "%~1.pdf"

rem create master PDF
if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode "%~1.tex"
if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode "%~1.tex"
if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode "%~1.tex"
if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex "%~1.tex"

rem remove unnecessary files
for %%x in (aux log out toc nav snm) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")

rem save the master file name
set master=%~1
shift

:loop
if "%~1"=="" goto :eof
copy "%master%.pdf" "%~1.pdf" 
shift
goto :loop

rem remove the master PDF if you want 
rem if exist "%master%.pdf" del "%master%.pdf"
```

### How to use:

Compile your `foo.tex` with the following command  typed in the CMD window.

```
pdflatexdup foo a b c d e f g
```

where `a`, `b`, `c`, ... `g` are the duplicate file names. After compilation you will get 8 99.99% identical PDF files (including the master PDF).

If you duplicate names contain spaces then you need to enclose it with quotes as follows:

```
pdflatexdup foo a b c d e f g "garbage collector"
```

In this case you get 9 PDF files as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can run LaTeX inside LaTeX when you run it as `pdflatex -shell-escape` (MikTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\write18{pdflatex --jobname="\jobname xy" \jobname}
\begin{document}
Hello Copy!
\end{document}
```

This has the advantage that the second run can be slightly different, for example another page layout.

Comment: Just be careful, because the inside `pdflatex` will see `\write18` again and call another `pdflatex` etc. etc. So maybe adding some if clause that will not call it again if `\jobname=...xy`.

Comment: @tohecz I thought of this myself. But unless the `\write18` contains `-shell-escape` is there any risk?

Comment: I'm not sure about the possiblity to change the default setting. The experience says: the more carefulness the better!

Comment: The request was _identical_ files. PDF files, generated by pdfTeX contains some randomness (ID values, font name prefixes). Also the status of the auxiliary files is quite difficult to handle. And if the document contains `\today` and the second document is generated a few seconds later right after midnight, &hellip;

Comment: @tohecz The "inner" run will not execute the `\write18` operation, unless the restrictions on shell-escape have been removed from `texmf.cnf`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek My first idea was `\write18{copy …}` but that failed for obvious reason (PDF not finished). I did not think of [`\AtEndDocument`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74250/16595) which kind of works (it copies the pdf from the first run).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek The only way to get two *identical* files (apart from the file system timestamps) is copying: do you agree?

Comment: @egreg Copying and hard links.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek The hard link is cheating. :) Besides you can't have them on a well known OS.

Comment: @egreg Windows: `mklink /H fooxy.pdf foo.pdf`. (But also the file system should support hard links and the hard links cannot cross file systems.)

Answer (score 3):

It has been tested many times in my daily projects. Compile it with `pdflatex --shell-escape executor.tex`. And you will get 5 PDF files: 4 identical PDF files (`a.pdf`, `b.pdf`, `c.pdf`, `d.pdf`) and `executor.pdf` that can be regarded as a log file.

```
% this file name is executor.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape executor.tex

\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\LaTeX\ is fun!
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}



\makeatletter
% make a master 
\immediate\write18{pdflatex foo.tex}
\@for\ext:={tex,dvi,ps,log,aux,out,toc,nav,snm}\do{\immediate\write18{cmd /c del foo.\ext}}%
% make multiple copies
\@for\filename:={a,b,c,d}\do{\immediate\write18{cmd /c copy foo.pdf \filename.pdf}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Done!
\end{document}
```

### Explanation:

The `executor.tex` is an auxiliary input file to automate the process of compiling the `foo.tex` for multiple output names (`a.pdf`, `b.pdf`, `c.pdf`, `d.pdf`).

### Disclaimer:

The multiple copies are not guaranteed to be 100% identical because the time stamp (creation date time, etc) for each file might not be identical.

Comment: 1) You're mising 2nd dash in front of `jobname=`. 2) Isn't it a windows-only solution? If so, maybe add a comment about it ;)

Comment: Won't this generate one PDF that says "LaTeX is fun" and one that produces "Done"?

Comment: @tohecz As it stands, yes, but you could use `ifplatform` to sort that.

Comment: @Jake: The `executor.tex` is an auxiliary input file to automate the process of compiling the `foo.tex` for multiple output names.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: Ah! Okay, I understand. Nice idea!

Answer (score 2):

Within LaTeX in a linux system could be:

```
% Need --enable-write18 or --shell-escape 
\immediate\write18{cp foo.pdf fooxy.pdf}
```

Or instead of `cp`  (copy) you can call any other command (a script running pdflatex several times, for example).

Addendum: In a Windows system could be (not tested):

```
\immediate\write18{foo.bat}
```

Where `foo.bat` is a simple text file with .bat extension that contain the following text:

```
pdflatex foo.tex
copy foo.pdf fooxy.pdf
del foo.aux
del foo.log
```

But this have no sense, because then the simplest way is to execute the batch file alone:

```
C:\SOMEDIR> foo
```

Comment: And where do you put this? Because LaTeX truncates the pdf fale at the beginning of the compilation, so `foo.pdf` contains just some mess when you call this!

Comment: I use Windows ...

Comment: In the preamble (obviously need n+1 runs that with a single copy). I left to imagination that the command ("any other command") could be the pdflatex itself.

Comment: @lpdbw, Windows also used to have a copy command (copy), but the important thing is that you can execute any windows command, including a custom `foo.bat` that do this and three or four more things).

Answer (score 2):

The questioner stated [in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/automatically-create-two-pdf-output-files-from-one-tex-file#comment158141_74247) that they use Windows.

My solution contains of two files (see below).
Inside the TeX file the batch file is run with the `start` command.
This issues a second process so that pdfLaTeX "thinks" that the `\write18` macro already ended and so that it finishes the PDF creating process without waiting for the copy process (which would copy an outdated or non-existent PDF).

### Files

#### `foo.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write18{start "write18 call" /MIN kopie.bat \jobname\space xy}}%
\begin{document}
Hello real copy!
\end{document}
```

#### `kopie.bat`

```bsh
@ECHO OFF
ping 127.0.0.1 /n 2
copy %1.pdf %1%2.pdf
exit
```

### Explanation

The `ping` command is simply to pass some time. The amount of pings that is needed for LaTeX to finish the pdf is empiric for this document. I expect for a big document that you need more time. (Windows 7 offers `timeout /T 2` for a two-second wait.)
There is probably also a way to wait for the `pdflatex` process to exit.

`\jobname` is `foo` (for the batch file it will be saved in `%1`). `xy` stands for the variable suffix you want to add (could be macro, too).

If you want to copy `foo` to `moo` you can edit the copy command to:

```bsh
copy %1.pdf %2.pdf
```

### Note

If you need to use `bib(la)tex`, `makeindex` or something of the sort you are better off using [`make`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74253/16595), an advanced batch script or you tweak your editor's build chain.

Comment: `cmd /c` is more convenient than `start` because you don't need to close the DOS window manually.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ `cmd /c` doesn't start a new instance (`cmd /c start …` does, though), so we're back two square one. I also found the switch `/B` for `start` and `exit` but I was still in some weird mode (blank line) or in the `pdflatex` process.