# Compile \showtrue and \showfalse to different target files

Tags: conditionals

I'm writing a problem set with a solution. Right now I have the following setup:

```
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\newif\ifshow
\showfalse

\ifshow
    \newenvironment{bluesol}
    {\begin{sol} \color{NavyBlue}}
    {\end{sol}}
\else
    \excludecomment{bluesol}
\fi
```

So my solutions would be in the `bluesol` environment.

Currently, if I want to compile a problem set questions, I'd do `\showfalse`, and when I want to compile the solutions, I'd do `\showtrue` instead. This works... but the output files are the same, so I have to manually change the file name to something like `pset1questions.pdf` before compiling the solutions.

I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically do this; i.e. run once for `\showfalse`, and rename the target file to `pset1questions.pdf`, and run again for `\showtrue`, and rename the target file to `pset1sol.pdf`

I'm also open to a completely new way to do this (but I still would like my solutions to be within the environment though).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And there are perhaps better ways to achieve this: `probsoln`, `answers`, `exsheets` etc.

Comment: here is your answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/automatically-create-two-pdf-output-files-from-one-tex-file

Comment: @touhami: I think the problem is `inside` ... but as long as the O.P. does not provide a clear MWE, it's difficult to tell

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. suppose your file is `question.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheorem{sol}{Solution}

%\newif\ifshow    % uncomment this line for normal use

% uncomment next line for solutions
%\showtrue

\ifshow
    \newenvironment{bluesol}
    {\begin{sol} \color{blue}}
    {\end{sol}}
\else
    \excludecomment{bluesol}
\fi

\begin{document}
This is a question
\begin{bluesol}
Here is the solution
\end{bluesol}
\end{document}
```

Note: you need `\showtrue` as `\showfalse` is the defaut value.

in this approch we dont need `\newif\ifshow` and `\showtrue`

we compile in line command:

```
pdflatex \newif\ifshow\showtrue \input{question.tex} && copy question.pdf solution.pdf
```

and then

```
pdflatex \newif\ifshow \input{question.tex}
```

Comment: `pdflatex` accepts the option `-jobname=solution`