# Passing arguments to latex file

Tags: pgfplots, recursion

I have a pgfplots main.tex file which plots a graph from an input file. I would like to run it on 100 input files and automate creating 100 PDF pictures. How can I do that?

The files are named as frame1, frame2, ..., frame100.

Comment: Inside main.tex `\foreach \frame in {frame1,frame2,...,frame100}{<code that plots from a file where you substitute the file name with \frame>}`.

Comment: This draws each plot on previous plot, so that you get only one plot. I need 100 PDF plots, each cropped based on standalone class.

Comment: I think `standalone` has an option `multi={tikzpicture}` so every `tikzpicture` gets its own page.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files or, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/automatically-create-two-pdf-output-files-from-one-tex-file, or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162042/multiple-pdf-generation-with-one-tex-file or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to pass an argument to a TeX file is `pdflatex "\\def{\\foo}{bar}\\include{filename}"`.

For example, say `filename.tex` contains the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The passed-in argument was ``\eggs.''
\end{document}
```

Then, if I compile it with `pdflatex "\\def\\eggs{wine}\\include{filename}"`, the PDF says 'The passed-in argument was "wine." '

This allows you to pass arguments to a TeX file in a shell script, which to me is usually easier than trying to get one call to pdflatex to output multiple PDFs; it also doesn't need `\write18`.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..100}
do
    pdflatex "\\def\\inputname{frame$i}\\include{main}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Works good. The braces around {1..100} should be removed though. Either "for i in 1 2 3" or "for (( i=0 ; i < 101 ; i++ )); do"