# Output Filename

Tags: jobname

I'm using texmaker and PdfLaTeX. With the exception of changing the `.tex` filename, does anyone know how to modify the output file name based on a parameter?

I am aware that the following line...

```
%& -job-name=XYZ
```

if placed at the beginning of the document would be parsed as an additional parameter. In the above case this would instruct the generation of `XYZ.pdf` when typeset, therefore:

```
%& -job-name=XYZ_26Dec2012
```

would accordingly produce `XYZ_26Dec2012.pdf`

How can I get the `26Dec2012` to change based on the actual date (automatically), therefore keeping a chronology of working documents as they change over time?

Comment: A 'pure' solution is not possible, unless you are able to extend your engine to interpret special characters in the job-name. Without that support, one would need to execute some *TeX code first and then set the job-name. This is not possible, as discussed in [How to influence the name of the pdf file created with pdfLaTeX (from within the source code)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19182). Hence, the remaining solutions involve writing a script to invoke the engine with an appropriate job-name, copying the file after compilation, or configuring the editor somehow to do one of these things.

Comment: I suspected as much. After posting the above, I found some Python scripts somewhere that pretty much did that. Cant be arsed, too much effort for a bees-d*ck of a benefit....

Comment: You could also use some VCS (e.g. Git), in which you commit both source and PDF file, so that you can go back to meaningful point (these tend not to coincide with date changes).

Comment: I'd also recommend a VCS for a history. If you don't want this, you can extend your "Quick Build" command with a script, that copies `XYZ.pdf` to `XYZ_26Dec2012.pdf`.

Comment: Would you consider using [`arara`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker) in `Texmaker` to build your documents?

Comment: @Daniel Never heard of arara, also I have actually moved across to texstudio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a unix system where the `date` command is available, you could replace

```
XYZ
```

by

```
XYZ_$(date +"%d%b%Y")
```

as the `-jobname` value, either in your first line at the beginning of your document (untested, I don't use texmaker) or in your compile command (tested).