# Integration of arara in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, arara

The [documentation of `arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) has a chapter about *IDE integration*. However the often used editor [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html) is missing. The installation of the tool itself is well described in the [documentation of `arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara)

- How can I integrate the great tool [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) in [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html)?
- Is it possible to define a new button?
- Are there any differences between the integration in different OS?

<sub>A small introduction with pictures would be nice :-)</sub>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One has at least two options, defining a *User command*, or using *Quick build*. There is no difference between Windows and Linux (AFAIR, I'll check later), can't say about OS X.

### User command

Go to User ⭢ User commands ⭢ Edit User commands.

[image]

Edit one of the free commands, give it a reasonable name, and use

```
arara %.tex
```

as the command. `%` is a placeholder for the filename without extension, as mentioned in the dialog:

[image]

### Quick build

The Quick build is defined in Options ⭢ Configure Texmaker ⭢ Quick build. Choose *User*, and type the same command as above:

[image]

### Use

- User commands can be accessed via the menu, or the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *function key*, as seen in the first screenshot.
- The quick build has keyboard shortcut <kbd>F1</kbd>, and is also found in the Tools menu. (The shortcut can be changed in Options ⭢ Configure ⭢ Shortcuts)
- There is a build button on the toolbar, and this can be configured to use anyone of the defined build tools, including user commands. Click the name of the tool to open a list of all available build tools, and click the arrow to compile.

  [image]

  I do not think it is possible to create a new button altogether.

Comment: Great. Now Texmaker users can work with arara ;-)

Comment: this procedure is same on linux(ubuntu) as well, i hope its same for mac. may be add `arara  %.tex --verbose --log |evince %.pdf` in both `user command` and `QuickBuild` approaches with `Built-in-viewer` and `Embed` ticked. Depending on pdfviewer choice, output pdf will automatically refresh in integrated pdf viewer on each run. customizing [QuickBuild User](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=256#c1)

Comment: Seems to work, but I don't have any progressoutput of arara

Comment: @NobbZ Try with `arara --verbose %.tex` instead. I'll see about editing my answer. See also texenthusiast's comment above.

Comment: Nope, as soon as I use the verbose option, arara uses \LaTeX in interactive mode and in case of error I don't even get an information about it, instead it looks like still compiling. Just seeing the arara headline and success message for every working-item would be enough, just like I can see it in my terminal when I run `arara` there

Comment: @NobbZ I see. I suppose this has something to do with how Texmaker passes information from compilers, but I'm not really an expert on the program, so I don't know how to get this working. You could ask a new question about the problem.