# How to arrange references at the end of each chapter (in a Thesis)?

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I am writing my PhD thesis and my supervisor has asked me to append the references at the end of each chapter. However, the template (which I am using) is unable to do so. I have downloaded this template, somewhere from the Internet.

I am using `\printbibliography` at the end of the chapters but still I can't see any references at the end. As a MWE ([Thesis_Template](http://www.sendspace.com/file/md53qu)), I am using two chapters with one common reference (Bannerman_2009) and a different reference (Chan05). I can see their proper citation in the text (Please see pg. no. 17 and 19 in `main.pdf`) but they are not being listed at the end. I am very worried because my professor want chapters for the review but my thesis is still not in the specified format. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXstudio for compiling the code.

Please explain elaborately, where I am making a mistake or there is some specific order of compiling the code, which I have to follow. Looking forward to your kind and prompt help.

My files are as follows:

%%% Main.tex %%%

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=numeric- comp,bibstyle=numeric,hyperref=true,backref=false,refsection=chapter,sorting=none,abbreviate=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{main}%%% the bibtex file
\defbibheading{thesisChapterBib}{\section{References}}
\begin{document}
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\appendix
\end{document}
```

%%% Chapter1.tex %%%

```
\chapter{Example One} 
This is a part of chapter one.~\cite{Bannerman_2009}
\printbibliography[heading=thesisChapterBib]
```

%%% Chapter2.tex %%%

```
\chapter{Example Two} 
Chapter with Nunc vitae placerat ligula.~\cite{Bannerman_2009, Chan05}
\printbibliography[heading=thesisChapterBib]
```

%%% main.bib %%%

```
@ARTICLE{Bannerman_2009,
   author = {Bannerman, M. N.},
   title = {Discrete potentials are good},
   journal = {J. M. B.},
   year = {2009},
   volume = {1},
   pages = {1-100},
   owner = {mjki2mb2},
}
@ARTICLE{Chan05,
   author = {Chan, R.H. and Chung-Wa Ho and Nikolova, M.},
   title = {Salt-and-pepper noise removal by median-type noise detectors and
    detail-preserving regularization},
   journal = {Image Processing, IEEE Transactions on},
   year = {2005},
   volume = {14},
   pages = {1479-1485},
   number = {10},
   doi = {10.1109/TIP.2005.852196},
   issn = {1057-7149}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem directly in the question. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The template works for me. You have to run `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex.

Comment: Which version of `biblatex` do you use? You can add the command `\listfiles` to print a File List at the end of your log file. Do you get any errors? You example works fine for me.

Comment: Daniel, can you please mention the steps/order of execution of the program (along with the platform and tools being used).

How can I check the version of biblatex? I am using MikTex 2.9.

Comment: Which editor do you use. To simplify the compilation steps I recommend `arara`. As a MikTeX user you have to install arara manually. The order of compilation is `pdflatex->biber->pdflatex->pdflatex`

Comment: I use TexStudio. I have installed arara on my machine. I can compile using pdflatex in TexStudio, but I don't know how to use biber.

What is the use of installing arara? Can you please throw some light on it.

Comment: TeXStudio is like TeXMaker so this one will help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker ... Now you can put the following lines at the begin of you main document: `% arara: pdflatex`, `% arara: biber`, `% arara: pdflatex`, `% arara: pdflatex` and all needed compilations are done by one compiling klick of `arara`

Comment: Using % arara: pdflatex, % arara: biber, % arara: pdflatex, % arara: pdflatex is like comment in the main.tex so how it will work actually because I tried doing the steps mentioned by you but still I am unable to get the reference appended at the end of the chapters.

I also have Ubuntu 12.10 so please tell me the easiest way by which I can get the output. arara doesn't seems to work in my case (It might be a case that I am unable to properly install it).