# Shortcut to compile the .tex and .bib in one go with Texmaker?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, texmaker

As known, Texmaker requires the user to PDFLaTeX first, then BibTeX, and then PDFLaTeX twice.

This is really tedious. Is there any shortcut that allows me to do it in one go?

**Update:**

Some say that it can be done by the so-called quick build.
But I have checked my quick build options as shown. There is **no** such a proper option called **"PDFLaTeX + BibTeX + view PDF"**.

[image]

How may I make it possible in this case?

Comment: There is a command "Quick Build" that should take care of this.

Comment: @karlkoeller  Please see editted version.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @karlkoeller  4.0.2

Comment: Click on "User" and then on "Wizard". At this point click "pdflatex" and then "Add", and so on.

Comment: have a look at the `arara` tool- details of how to configure it are [Integration of arara in Texmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107989)

Comment: Is there a way to set this up for TeXworks?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use the "User" quick build command (or one of the user commands in the "User" menu).

1. Options -> configure Texmaker -> Quick build : select "User"
2. Click on the "wizard" button and add "pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex, pdf viewer"
3. Just use the "quick build" command on your document (F1)

[image]

Comment: This is the same I wrote in my comment...

Comment: Note that it would be better to add "pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex, view pdf" or else you risk to have not your references linked correctly.

Comment: Sorry for my answer. When i began to make the snapshot and write my message, your comment was not yet published.

Comment: Don't worry, it's OK. But add one more pdflatex run in your answer!

Comment: It should be a default option available in QuickBuild instead of a UserCommand  as it's widely used by many

Comment: My version of Texmaker (4.4.1) offers a default quickbuild option "pdflatex+bib(la)tex+pdflatex(x2)+view pdf". So the custom user command is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As of version TexMaker 4.4.1 (or earlier) the suggestion from user27168 exists as option 2 for quick build

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recognize that this is an old post but it is new for me.

I changed the quick build option to my new user defined quick button. To do this, I clicked on the drop down menu button next to the quick build arrow 
[image: quick build before]

and chose my newly created user option.[image: new]

Now with one push of the button, not only have I compiled by document, thanks user27168, but it also outputs an updated pdf file.

Comment: This is more a comment to user27168's post, isn't it? You only show that one may select a different command instead of Quick Build, don't you?

Comment: If I am remembering correctly, it is a modification of quick build. Instead of quick build, which you have to hit a number of times, you can make your own compile function which will compile after one application.