# arara - How to see errors and pdf with in Texmaker Windows

Tags: texmaker, rules, windows, arara, document-configuration

How could we check the errors in TexMaker and also generate the PDF automatically? I am unable to do it for the moment. Using the following as comments

I followed the installation process correctly as explained in the manual. However, I do not have any configuration file. Maybe that's a problem, I am not sure how could I build a configuration file within Windows. Below is the order or `arara` commands that I add to my source file.

[Installation procedure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker/186560?noredirect=1#comment431706_186560)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

Comment: Could you way more about what goes wrong: any error messages?

Comment: The error message is as `Process started, Process exited with error(s)`

Comment: the problem is I don't see any errors similar to when i do the Pdflatex, also i have to switch to Pdflatex to see the pdf file, it does not do the same automatically, even if i initiate the command in the beginning