# Multiple Quick Build Options

Tags: texmaker

I utilize these quick build options in TexMaker:

1.) "PdfLaTeX + View PDF" and 
2.) "PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View Pdf"

I can't quite seem how to bind one of these options to say "F2"

I.E. I set quick build to 1.) ... which means pressing "F1" will do it ...but I wish to set 2.) to "F2".

Comment: You can edit the shortcut keys of the editor in the Settings for change the LaTeX option in the F2 key to your own build option.

Comment: You should consider using arara: see [Integration of arara in Texmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/) and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation/77879#77879