# Arara and TexMaker problem

Tags: texmaker, arara

I'm trying to use arara in TexMaker. MWE I am trying to compile is:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

Right away I get the following error:

```
Process started

Process exited with error(s)
```

However no error is shown. I tried following this procedure:

[Integration of arara in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker)

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked that `arara` is correctly installed? (Try running `arara` from the command prompt.)