# Post build processes with shell script and write18

Tags: shell-escape, scripts

I would like to start a shell script from LaTeX. In the shell script I need to wait until the .pdf file is generated and afterwards I want to do some stuff with this file.

So I created a MWE `Test.tex` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\immediate\write18{/myPath/script.sh}
\begin{document}
  Test
\end{document}
```

The shell script `script.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
until [ -f Test.pdf ]
do
     sleep 5
done
echo "File found"
# Do SOMETHING
```

Unfortunately this seems not to work with TeXMaker. It seems to hang in an endless loop and probably the `sleep 5` cmd seems also to let TeXMaker fall asleep.

**BTW**
`--shell-escape` is enabled and `chmod 755 script.sh` is set.

**EDIT**
Now I'm able to use `arara` like this in my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes,synctex: yes,interaction: nonstopmode}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

But how to tell `arara` now to run this script     `\immediate\write18{/myPath/script.sh}` after the pdf is generated?

Comment: no that won't work. Why don't you use an external script that first calls pdflatex and then your postprocessing? You could e.g. use arara to set this up.

Comment: Hmm that‘s a pity. I would like to combine this scripting with my normal workflow in TexMaker. Otherwise I have to execute the external script after every TexMaker build. Or do you know a possibility to have a post build script execution in TexMaker?

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker and other questions.

Comment: If texmaker is able to run builds combining pdflatex + bibtex +makeindex then it should also be able to run other tools and scripts.

Comment: I have edited my question, could you please have a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, at the end the solution is much easier than expected.

I had to change my IDE from TexMaker to TexStudio. In TexStudio you just has to add one single expression in the Meta Commands in `Preferences` => `Generate` => `Build and View`.

[image: Meta commands]

In my case it's `sh -c "/MyPath/script.sh argument1"`

That's it!