# Timestamp in document / pdf name

Tags: pdftex, pdf, compiling, datetime, jobname

Let's assume my document is called `test.tex`. Instead of creating a `test.pdf` I would like to add a suffix date stamp to the filename, e.g. `test_2013_05_29` (`test_yyyy_mm_dd`). I am compiling with pdfLaTeX and I would like this to work both on Windows and on Mac.

Comment: Can't do it, I'm told.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the

Comment: That said, you *can* add the datestamp to the file contents, with the command `\today` (I often place it in a header)

Comment: Oops. My earlier response refers to changing the name from within TeX. I hadn't considered the name change during invocation, as shown in the answer of alfC.  Of course, if external renaming is allowed, then just renaming the output following traditional compilation should apply under any operating system.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, good point anyway. Also, I am giving an answer that the OP may need to "test" in Windows, I am not sure how portable it is.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `-jobname` option (the order is important):

```
pdflatex -jobname=testDATE test.tex
```

(I am not sure how distribution-dependent this is, I am using `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2013/dev)`)

Also, in GNU/Linux-like system you can make this automatic from the command line as

```
pdflatex -jobname=test_`date +%Y_%m_%d` test.tex
```

(not sure if the `date` command works in the same way in Mac)

This solution is not perfect with respect to the compilation process, since `aux`iliary files will be labeled in the same way, so compilation will be "discontinuous" across days, which may not be serious. I think it may be safer to do (the good old) change of name after compilation if you can, for example in GNU/Linux:

```
pdflatex test.tex && mv/cp test.pdf test_`date +%Y_%m_%d`.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a package `varsfromjobname`, that allows you to extract certain parts from the name of the document.

Find it under http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/varsfromjobname