# How can i use eclipse to use the date and version in my output filename

Tags: output, jobname, eclipse

This is less a direct LaTeX question than it is about compiling LaTeX.

I am using eclipse and in my project properties i set `Output File = document.pdf` . My demoproject compiles and outputs the File.

What i want is to define something like `document_$DATE$_$VERSION$.pdf` .

I want eclipse to generate the Date and i want my demoproject to set the Version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\Version{A}
\begin{document}
This is my document.
\end{document}
```

How would i do something like that?

Comment: Related [How to influence the name of the pdf file created with pdfLaTeX (from within the source code)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19182/15717)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide an indirect answer via `arara`. `:)`

This rule might do exactly what you want (untested on Windows, but I believe it works):

```
!config
identifier: renamer
name: Renamer
commands:
- <arara> @{isWindows("cmd /c rename", "mv")} "@{getBasename(file)}.pdf" "@{getBasename(file)}_@{date.concat(version)}.pdf"
arguments:
- identifier: date
  default: <arara> @{(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format(new java.util.Date())}
- identifier: version
  flag: <arara> @{"_".concat(parameters.version)}
```

I opted for the `yyyy-MM-dd` pattern, but this can be easily changed. `:)` The idea here is:

1. Get `foo.pdf`.
2. Get the current date (e.g, `2014-03-26`).
3. Append the date to the filename.
4. If any version provided via directive, append it as well.
5. `???`
6. Profit. `:)`

A quick example:

```
% arara: pdftex
% arara: renamer
Hello world!
\bye
```

Running `arara`:

```
paulo@alexandria paulo$ ls
vtest.tex
paulo@alexandria paulo$ arara vtest.tex 
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running PDFTeX... SUCCESS
Running Renamer... SUCCESS
paulo@alexandria paulo$ ls
vtest_2014-03-26.pdf  vtest.log  vtest.tex
```

If I want to append a version ID:

```
% arara: pdftex
% arara: renamer: { version: 'draft' }
Hello world!
\bye
```

And now:

```
paulo@alexandria paulo$ arara vtest.tex 
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running PDFTeX... SUCCESS
Running Renamer... SUCCESS
paulo@alexandria paulo$ ls
vtest_2014-03-26_draft.pdf  vtest_2014-03-26.pdf  vtest.log  vtest.tex
```

There we go! `:)`