# Copy file automatically with write18

Tags: shell-escape

With the following mini-template, I want to copy the distnate pdf file into another one automatically as I run `pdflatex` with `--shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Just a test.

\write18{cmd /c copy\jobname.pdf \jobname-print.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that this can't work, since the file `jobname.pdf` is using by the engine. I will get a copy of *empty* file of size `0`.

Also, please consider we are working in writing a `cls` file, it also expected to work as

```
\AtEndDocument{
\write18{cmd /c copy \jobname.pdf \jobname-print.pdf}
}
```

Comment: By the way, my plateform is Windows. But Linux also welcome...

Comment: also I try to use `\write18{cmd /c timeout 5 && copy \jobname.pdf \jobname-print.pdf}` but not work.

Comment: is `pdflatex -jobname print.pdf source.tex` from the command line an option (parameterized in a shell script)? See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the

Comment: You can't do it during compilation. Isn't it easier to use a simple script  (a `.bat` on Windows)?