# Defining the pdf output file within the document file using %& -job-name

Tags: pdftex, jobname

My understanding is that if I create a file called noName.tex with the first line

```
%& -jobname=myName
```

then when I run pdflatex on that file, the output file will be named myName.pdf rather than noName.pdf, just as if I'd typed

```
pdflatex -jobname=myName noName.tex
```

But in the following example, the first line is ignored by pdflatex, and the output is named noName.pdf.

Here is noName.tex:

```
%& -job-name=myName
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Could somebody advise what the correct syntax would be please?  Thanks very much.

The version of pdflatex I'm using is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2014.6.25)
```

Comment: Where exactly have you gotten the idea that this should be supported (not saying that it isn't?, I've never seen it before)

Comment: as @daleif ask what is the editor you use? This works fine for me with TeXstudio.

Comment: I saw reference to it in [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289152/defining-the-pdf-output-file-within-the-document-file-using-job-name?noredirect=1#comment699715_289152) thread.   But elsewhere also.    I'm using linux, so simply running pdflatex from the command line.   TeXstudio obviously has a lot of additional wrapping.

Comment: The line `%& -jobname=myName` is one of these so-called *magic comments*, which can be interpreted by *some editors* (TeXstudio, TeXworks).  This is hence not an intrinsic feature of `pdftex` and compiling from the command line will thus result in those magic comments being ignored.

Comment: @HenriMenke No, this is a magic line for the TeX engine and is not interpreted by editors, as far as I know. Some implementations of TeX allow `-jobname` there some don't: MiKTeX does, TeX Live doesn't.

Comment: Related question [jobname - How to influence the name of the pdf file created with pdfLaTeX (from within the source code)? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%&` magic line has been supported by implementations of TeX from many years. However, the feature is implemented differently in the various TeX distributions.

Note that no editor/front-end I know of interprets such a line: this is specific for the TeX engine.

In TeX Live, the line can contain only the specification of a format to be loaded and a TCX file, see section 3.5.2.2 in the documentation of Web2c (`texdoc web2c`, page 11 for TeX Live 2015):

```
%&format -translate-file=tcxfile
```

Either part can be empty. Note that, in TeX Live, Knuth TeX *doesn't* honor this magic line.

As far as I know, other command line options such as `-jobname` can be specified with MiKTeX. They'll definitely not work with TeX Live.

Comment: I can confirm that the `pdflatex` executable included in MacTeX (2020) ignores the “magic comment” `%& -jobname=myName` or `%& -job-name=myName`.

By contrast, the `pdflatex` executable included in MiKTeX for the Mac _does_ take the magic comment `%& -job-name=myName` into account.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using TeXstudio with TeX Live/MacTeX, you can include the line

`% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[-jobname=myName]`

at the beginning of your document to specify `myName` as the name of the output file.