# Preprocessing LaTeX with the help of arara

Tags: arara, abc

I wrote a perl script (teximporter) to facilitate the use of in-line foreign
textual notation inclusion in LaTeX. Typically, it calculates a set of files (images, attach, ...) and a latex replacement string. Example:

```
\inline_abc[midi,width=\textwidth]{
X:1
T:Dó-Ré-Mi
K:Emaj
M:2/4
EF G2 | GG G2 | GA B2 | BB B2 | AG F2 | FF F2 | GF E>E|EE E2||
}
```

After

```
teximport ex.tex > _ti_ex.tex
pdflatex _ti_ex.tex
```

we got the expected result (a pdf image and a midi attach), 
[image]
In order to hide command line activity (for IDEs), I decided to try arara. Here is my teximporter.yaml

```
!config
identifier: teximporter
name: teximporter
commands:
-  teximporter -o "_ti_@{file}" "@{file}" 
-  pdflatex "_ti_@{file}" 
arguments: []
```

But the final pdf file has the wrong name (`_pi_ex.pdf` instead of `ex.pdf`).

What is the best way to define a good `arara` configuration for a preprocessor, if possible capable of running in Linux, Windows and Mac.

Comment: According to the rule that you've specified, I'd say that `_ti_ex.pdf` is the appropriate name of the `pdf`. You could add another line to rename the `pdf`, which I have done in, for example, my answer to : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs. For reference, you might like to see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the

Comment: Hello João! Chris (@cmhughes) is right, when running `pdflatex` on a file named `a.tex`, you end up with a PDF file named `a.pdf`, so the current result is expected. Is `_ti_ex.pdf` the file you were expecting, only with the "wrong" name? If so, it is just a matter of writing a "rename" command in the list of commands. Chris wrote a solution for that, but I can come up with another solution if you want more features to be added to your rule. `:)`

Comment: @cmhughes, thank you! in the suggested answers I learn some very nice tricks  like `isWindows("...", "..."` and `-jobname` -- this way I see 2 good ways to write a system independent rename.

Comment: @PauloCereda, muito obrigado! After Chris wise suggestions I will begin by trying ` -  pdflatex -jobname="@{getBasename(file)}" "_ti_@{file}"` This way it will work with some IDEs and in the music files, we just need a simple `% arara: teximport`.

Comment: That's great! Perhaps you could self answer with your implementation :)

Comment: @cmhughes and @ PauloCereda, I tried to write down what I leaned so far: please correct my mistakes ...

Answer (score 1):

This is not really my answer: all the wisdom came from @cmhughes and others (see references in the comments).

The configuration presented in question has some problems:

- the pdf output for file `a.tex` is `_pi_a.pdf` -- problematic for the IDEs' users : rename needed
- it forces the use of `pdflatex` : parameter needed

Following the new version of configuration `teximporter.yaml` :

```
!config
identifier: teximporter
name: teximporter
commands:
-  <arara> teximporter -o _ti_@{file} @{file} 
-  <arara> @{engine} -jobname=@{getBasename(file)} _ti_@{file}

arguments:
- identifier: engine
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.engine}
  default: pdflatex
```

Comments:

- `jobname=@{getBasename(file)}` : renames output and auxiliary files to the initial basename (`a.pdf`, `a.aux`, etc)
- `@{engine}`  : defines a parameter (default: pdflatex) to be possible
  to choose different latex engines (lualatex, etc) (copied from @cmhughes)

To use teximporter preprocessor, add the following to the "tex" file:

```
% arara : teximporter
```

or

```
% arara : teximporter: { engine : lualatex }
```

And it is possible to directly use arara as the processor in IDEs like TexWorks.