# foreach LaTeX input file, output a PDF file

Tags: pdftex, shell-escape, pgffor, filecontents

I have a bunch of tables saved in separate files and folders which I have compiled with a master file, commenting the name of each file in the master file one by one and tediously renaming the resulting PDF output.

I have over one hundred tables produced over several months. Now I would like to recompile them all in a different style, so I'm looking for a way to automate the process.

Below is an unsuccessful attempt that builds on several suggestions found on this site, particularly [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the).

To summarise in words what I tried to do in the code below:

1. create files `a.tex` and `b.tex` to be used as inputs (these
   are my tables);
2. define a command to store the file names as a
   list, `a` and `b` (no need to automate file naming);
3. a `foreach` loop (package `pgffor`) to call each input file
   `a.tex` and `b.tex` inside a basic document header/preamble
   (`standalone` class) and save it with the name `temp.tex`;
4. followed by a call to `\immediate\write18{pdflatex...` to run
   pdflatex on `temp.tex`;
5. the intended output is two PDF files
   named `a.pdf` and `b.pdf`. I'm running this with
   `shell-escape` enabled.

Needless to say it's not working and help is appreciated!

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}% \foreach
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{a.tex}
  First file (a table without preamble)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{b.tex}
  Second file (a table without preamble)
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\ListOfFiles}{a,b}

\foreach \x in \ListOfFiles{%
  \begin{filecontents*}{temp.tex}%
    \documentclass{standalone}%
    %\usepackage{stylesforalltables}
    \begin{document}%
    \input{\x}
    \end{document}%
  \end{filecontents*}%
  \immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\x\space temp}
}%
```

Comment: why do you need to make a loop in tex? if I had a directory full of tex files I'd just write `for i in *.tex; do pdflatex $i;done` and get a directory full of pdf. (That's bash but you could do the same in any commandline .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - it seems the tables are not actually complete documents. So, he needs a way to process each table as a document fragment. Maybe `for file in table*.tex; do ln -s $file temp.tex; pdflatex template.tex; mv template.pdf $(file%.tex).pdf; done`. This assumes that names of all table source files start with `table`, and that the `template.tex` file sets up the desired document format and contains `\input{temp}` in the document body.

Comment: Please 1) don't use `filecontents`  as argument of a command 2) don't use `%` at the end of line with `\begin{filecontents*}{temp.tex}%` 3)  try `\input{\jobname}` instead of `\input{\x}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, a bash/commandline solution would be perfectly acceptable for a one-off, but I'm also interested in a cross-platform solution that would be easy to explain to my co-authors (in this project I do not have co-authors, but in other cases I do, so I'm interested in learning of other ways). Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer, your interpretation is correct, thanks for the solution!

Comment: @touhami, thanks! not sure why ``\jobname`` instead of ``\x``, but it's easy enough to remember. Is there a short explanation for the layman for why a loop over ``filecontents`` wouldn't work?

Comment: `filecontents` writes `verbatim` so  in `temp.tex` we get `\input{\x}` and `\x` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot touhami. By the way your answer and egreg's were a tie, as both answered my question and worked perfectly. I picked egreg's only because it was the closest to my original attempt, for no better reason. Both answers are great. Thanks again.

Comment: you're welcome, egreg's answer is better (as always).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `filecontents` in the argument to another command. But you can define the master file in a separate `filecontents` environment. Call this `compileall.tex` (or whatever)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}% \foreach
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{master.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage{stylesforalltables}
\begin{document}
\input{\jobname}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{a.tex}
  First file (a table without preamble)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{b.tex}
  Second file (a table without preamble)
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\ListOfFiles}{a,b}

\foreach \x in \ListOfFiles{%
  \immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\x\space master}
}

\stop
```

However, it's simpler to have `master.tex` written as above and do, from the command line (assuming `bash`)

```bsh
for i in {a,b}; do pdflatex -jobname=$i master; done
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefer the non-command line solution, as I tend to edit documents with ``texstudio`` and compile them by pressing on the F12 key (my shortcut), plus I use MacOS, Linux, Windows  almost indifferently (depending on whether I'm at home, the office, etc) and shell commands are not always cross-platform. But it's certainly good to have as a reference.

Comment: Note to self: As I have my tables saved in folders with the same name, I wrote ``\input{\jobname/\jobname}`` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution (with simple `\write`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}% \foreach
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{a.tex}
  First file (a table without preamble)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{b.tex}
  Second file (a table without preamble)
\end{filecontents*}


\newcommand*{\ListOfFiles}{a,b}


\newwrite\temp
\foreach \x in \ListOfFiles{
\immediate\openout\temp=temp.tex
\immediate\write\temp{
    \string\documentclass{standalone}
    \string\begin{document}
    \string\input{\x}
    \string\end{document}
}
\immediate\closeout\temp
\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\x\space temp}
}%

\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

Or (shorter) with `\unexpanded`

```
\immediate\write\temp{\unexpanded{%
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \begin{document} 
    \input{\jobname} 
    \end{document}}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I like the second solution better, with ``\unexpanded``, as it makes it easier to type a longer preamble.