# Add date in output name

Tags: pdftex, emacs, datetime, jobname

`pdflatex` command allows to specify an output name through `--job-name=` option. But can't insert the date and time automatically.

Emacs could do it:

```
(compile-command "pdflatex --job-name=myoutputname.pdf myfile.tex")
```

How can the compile-command be modified to automatically add the date and time in the output name?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the

Comment: It works perfectly though, but doesn't allow to insert the date automatically... Maybe the post should be in Emacs forum rather ? (Many thanks anyway !)

Comment: Yes, it was not supposed to work perfectly. It was just a pointer. I faced this issue before where I had to control the .pdf output name of around 4000 files (to be auto compiled by a script). Finding no other alternative, I generated each of 4000 plus .tex file in runtime (using LaTeX :-)) and then generated the .pdf's. And you are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably you can replace

```
"pdflatex --job-name=myoutputname.pdf myfile.tex"
```

by

```
(concat "pdflatex --job-name=myoutputname-"
    (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")
     ".pdf myfile.tex")
```

which produces

```
"pdflatex --job-name=myoutputname-2017-09-01.pdf myfile.tex"
```

Comment: oh I just noticed you wanted time as well, but you can add more `%` fields to the format string:-)

Comment: Yep, precisely : "%Y-%m-%d@%H-%M-%S" ;-p

Comment: Actually, I even wrote : (concat "pdflatex --job-name="
    (format-time-string "myoutputname-%Y-%m-%d@%H-%M-%S")
     ".pdf myfile.tex"), for newbies too...

Comment: please for newbies, what do I have to write? writing "pdflatex --job-name=myoutputname.pdf myfile.tex" in my command works, but was does the concat mean?

Comment: @acep `concat` is the emacs lisp function to concatenate (join together) strings.