# How can I automatically add the date to the output PDF file name?

Tags: compiling, date

Currently when I generate a PDF file of my document, it produces the name

```
document1.pdf
```

I'd like to set it so that it adds the current date (or the date produced by `\date{\today}`), such as

```
document1_March_15_2019.pdf
```

or however it may produce the date. Is there a method to do that? The closest I found was [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389351/add-date-in-output-name) but I'm not using an emac or pdftex, I think. I am using TexMaker on a Mac OS Mojave.

Comment: The command \date{\today} is a `LaTeX` command that will get its value during compilation from the `TeX` distro (for example `TeX Live` or `MacTeX`) that your `TeXmaker` is using. So, `TeXmaker` will never see this output of this command but will just let it printed in your pdf document via your `TeX` distro. So, try to find out if texmaker have available in a variable the current date and add this variable before the `.pdf` extension in your `TeXmaker` options at the output filename.

Comment: the pdf is made by latex (not texmaker) and is just the filename of your source file with `.tex` changed to `.pdf` so if you save the file as `hs-nebula.tex` then the generated file will be `hs-nebula.pdf` `document1` is presumably just a default file name if you start a blank file without saving it to a specific name (although I don't use texmaker to be sure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For editors that execute commands in a bash-based shell, you can modify the preferences of your editor to compile with

```
mydate=$(date +'%B_%d_%Y') ; pdflatex --jobname="document1_$mydate" %.tex
```

This will generate a pdf called `document1_March_15_2019.pdf`

Comment: Nice (+1)... I suggest an edit to remove the `TeXmaker` tag and the TeXmaker from the title to make the question/answer just specific to the OS (Linux/Mac) and not to the editor

Comment: @koleygr Feel free to edit

Comment: Just to clarify, do I add this to the PdfLaTeX box in texmaker >> Preferences or is this a user command?

Comment: Was commenting to ask the OP... but he did it before my question...

Comment: @HS-nebula You can do it either way. If you want to compile all your documents like this, you could directly modify the pdflatex preferences, if you only want to use it occasionally, a separate command might be better.

Comment: An alias could be useful to as additional info (if it works for mac too)

Comment: Okay, makes sense, but then is there a default variable for `document1`? Would it just be `--jobname="$DOCNAME_$mydate"` then? (assuming this is done in the pdflatex preferences)

Comment: This is a great answer but I'm just confused about where exactly to type this in the pdflatex preferences.