# Is there a simple way to build two pdfs from the same tex file?

Tags: jobname

I'm trying to hack together a way to generate solutions files to my quizzes and exams. Here is my current workflow.

I have a file `quiz.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\solutionscolor}{white}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\color{\solutionscolor}\normalfont\bfseries,
bodyfont=\color{\solutionscolor}
]{colored}

\declaretheorem[
style=colored,
% style=phantom,
name=Solution,
numbered=no
]{solution}

\newcommand{\fillblank}[2]{\underline{\hspace{#1}{\color{\solutionscolor}#2}\hspace{#1}}}

\title{Quiz}
\author{Name \fillblank{1.25in}{Solutions}}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{problem}
  Let $f(x)=\cos(2\,x)$. Determine the concavity of $f(x)$ at $x=\pi$.
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
  The first derivative of $f(x)$ may be computed using the chain rule
  \[
  f^{\prime}(x)
  = -\sin(2\,x)(2)
  = -2\sin(2\,x)
  \]
  The second derivative of $f(x)$ may then be computed by using the chain rule
  again
  \[
  f^{\prime\prime}(x)
  = -2\cos(2\,x)(2)
  = -4\cos(2\,x)
  \] 
  It follows that
  \[
  f^{\prime\prime}(\pi)=-4\cos(2\pi)=-4<0
  \]
  Since $f^{\prime\prime}(\pi)<0$, $f(x)$ is \emph{concave down} at $x=\pi$.
\end{solution}


\begin{problem}
  Fill in the blanks.
  \begin{align*}
    \sin(\pi) &= \fillblank{.25in}{0} &
    \cos(\pi) &= \fillblank{.25in}{-1} &
    \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) &= \fillblank{.25in}{1} &
    \cos(34\pi) &= \fillblank{.25in}{1} 
  \end{align*}
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this document produces `quiz.pdf`:

[image]

If I change the value of `\solutionscolor` to `blue`, the result looks like this:

[image]

My problem is that I want two files: `quiz.pdf` (with no solutions) and `quiz-solutions.pdf` (with solutions). Currently I have to do this manually.

Is there a way to automate my output to produce two files?

Comment: Have you seen the `exam` class? http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf

Comment: I'm aware of the exam class, but I'm very interested in a solution without without changing my document class.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick: Most likely you need an `\if...` switch then

Comment: Can an `\if...` switch redirect output to a different file name?

Comment: I believe one PDF per bulld is the limit, although some form of externalize or a script could probably do it.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that by default, `filename.tex` writes to `filename.pdf`.  But there are a few ways around that.  The first step is to remove the `\solutionscolor` newcommand from `quiz.tex`.

The easiest approach is to have two separate files:
`student.tex`:

```
\newcommand{\solutionscolor}{white}
\input quiz
```

`solutions.tex`:

```
\newcommand{\solutionscolor}{blue}
\input quiz
```

A slightly better idea may be to just have two commands that you use:

```
pdflatex -jobname solutions "\newcommand{\solutionscolor}{blue}\input quiz"
pdflatex -jobname student "\newcommand{\solutionscolor}{white}\input quiz"
```

Either approach doubles your aux and log files, and requires that you compile each document separately.  But you could have a script run things for you, or combine your commands into one:

```
pdflatex student ; pdflatex solutions
pdflatex -jobname solutions "\newcommand{\solutionscolor}{blue}\input quiz" ; pdflatex -jobname student "\newcommand{\solutionscolor}{white}\input quiz"
```

(You should be aware that white text is still present. Distributing the document electronically means that people could access the data you've hidden.)