# Is there a better way to generate a separate solutions file in the exam class?

Tags: exam

I write a lot of exams, quizzes, and homework problems for the course I teach. Whenever I write an evaluation `foo.tex`, I always want a separate solutions file `foo-solutions.tex` to be written. Here's an example of my workflow.

I start by writing the evaluation along with the solutions in a file `foo-solutions.tex`:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\printanswers

\newcommand{\checkforstudent}[1]{%
  \ifcsname#1\endcsname%
  \noprintanswers%
  \else%  ... command '#1' does not exist ...%
  \fi%
}


\begin{document}

\checkforstudent{studentmode}

\begin{questions}
  \question What is the first sentence of \emph{Moby Dick}?
  \begin{solution}
    \emph{Call me Ishmael.}
  \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The command `\checkforstudent` tests whether or not the input exists a a command. If so, then the answers are switched off. The first line after `\begin{document}` uses `\checkforstudent` to check for a command

Compiling this file generates `foo-solutions.pdf`:

[image: screen-shot of foo-solutions.pdf]

I also have a file `foo.tex`:

```
\newcommand{\studentmode}{}\input foo-solutions
```

This file defines the command `\studentmode` and then inputs the entirety of `foo-solutions.tex`. Compiling `foo.tex` generates `foo.pdf`:

[image: screen-shot of foo.pdf]

Finally, I have these two pdfs generated at once with a bash script `write-files.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

pdflatex foo-solutions.tex
pdflatex foo-solutions.tex

pdflatex foo
pdflatex foo
```

The script compiles both files twice to make sure all references are properly dealt with.

This workflow works reasonably well. However, there are some annoyances:

1. I have to keep track of three files instead of one (`foo-solutions.tex`, `foo.tex`, and `write-files.sh`).
2. When I write a new evaluation `bar.tex`, I copy `foo-solutions.tex`, `foo.tex`, and `write-files.sh` to a new directory and replace the instances of `foo` with `bar`. This *really* annoys me.
3. Many of my colleagues are not comfortable with running bash scripts. So, when I share my documents with them, they have trouble generating both the evaluation and the solutions.

It would be nice if there were a solution to my problem that allowed me to generate `foo-solutions.pdf` and `foo.pdf` with just one latex file.

Is this possible?

*Note.* My current workflow was inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403643/31016) to a [similar question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/403592/31016).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions posted here work well, but I think I've finally figured out an elegant solution using symlinks and `latexmk`.

The package [`currfile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/currfile?lang=en) can detect the name of the file being compiled by latex. The package [`xstring`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xstring?lang=en) has a function `\IfSubStr` that executes code conditioned on if a given string is a substring of another given string.

So, if we insert the line

```
\IfSubStr*{\currfilename}{solutions}{ \printanswers }{ \noprintanswers }
```

in our preamble, the exam class will print solutions if the file name contains the substring `solutions`.

Consider the solutions document `~/myexam/exam-solutions.tex`

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

\IfSubStr*{\currfilename}{solutions}{ \printanswers }{ \noprintanswers }

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question What is the first sentence of \emph{Moby Dick}?
  \begin{solution}
    \emph{Call me Ishmael.}
  \end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Issuing `ln -s ~/myexam/exam-solutions.tex ~/myexam/exam.tex` creates the symlink `exam.tex` linked to `exam-solutions.tex`. Running `latexmk` from `~/myexam/`, automatically generates both the bare exam and the solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Along with your first file (you called it `foo-solutions.tex`, but for this Makefile you should call it `foo.tex`) you can use the following Makefile:

```
TEX   = pdflatex
# if you want to use specific FLAGS for compilation
FLAGS =

FILE = $(wildcard *.tex)

STDVER = $(FILE:%.tex=%-students)
SOLVER = $(FILE:%.tex=%-solutions)
STDOPT = studentmode

STDPDF = $(STDVER).pdf
SOLPDF = $(SOLVER).pdf

all: $(STDPDF) $(SOLPDF)

$(STDPDF): $(FILE)
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) -jobname $(STDVER) "\def\$(STDOPT){}\input{$(FILE)}"
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) -jobname $(STDVER) "\def\$(STDOPT){}\input{$(FILE)}"
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) -jobname $(STDVER) "\def\$(STDOPT){}\input{$(FILE)}"
$(SOLPDF): $(FILE)
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) -jobname $(SOLVER) $(FILE)
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) -jobname $(SOLVER) $(FILE)
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) -jobname $(SOLVER) $(FILE)

.PHONY: clean clean_sol clean_std
clean: clean_sol clean_std
clean_sol:
    -rm -f $(SOLVER).*
clean_std:
    -rm -f $(STDVER).*
```

Put it in the same directory as your .tex-file called `Makefile`. In this directory should only be one .tex-file. If there are more change the line `FILE = $(wildcard *.tex)` to `FILE = <your-tex-files-name>.tex`. It produces two separate pdfs one called `<your-tex-files-name>-students.pdf` and one called `<your-tex-files-name>-solutions.pdf`. Call it from the shell with `make`.

This is a rather basic Makefile. It could use some enhancements, but should do the trick.

If you want to remove the created pdfs and auxiliary files, call `make clean` from the shell.

Answer (score 3):

1) Using the bash script you can easily avoid having two .tex files and simplify your code.

This can be your `foo.tex`:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question What is the first sentence of \emph{Moby Dick}?
  \begin{solution}
    \emph{Call me Ishmael.}
  \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

and the script to generate foo-exam.pdf and foo-solutions.pdf:

```
#!/bin/bash

pdflatex -jobname foo-exam "\documentclass{exam}\input foo"
pdflatex -jobname foo-exam "\documentclass{exam}\input foo"

pdflatex -jobname foo-solutions "\documentclass{exam}\printanswers\input foo"
pdflatex -jobname foo-solutions "\documentclass{exam}\printanswers\input foo"
```

2) You can also use just one script for all evaluations, by calling the script with a parameter, like `create-exam.sh foo`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "" ] && [ -f "${1}".tex ]; then

  pdflatex -jobname ${1}-exam "\documentclass{exam}\input ${1}"
  pdflatex -jobname ${1}-exam "\documentclass{exam}\input ${1}"

  pdflatex -jobname ${1}-solutions "\documentclass{exam}\printanswers\input ${1}"
  pdflatex -jobname ${1}-solutions "\documentclass{exam}\printanswers\input ${1}"

else
  echo "Syntax is:"
  echo "  create-exam name (where name.tex is the file to compile)"
fi
```

3) With the parameter, if you install the script to your colleagues in their PATH once, it will work for all evaluations.

There may be a solution without scripts by using `\immediate\write18{shell command}` but it would require activating this unsafe option in Latex and escaping characters in that command, which is very difficult. If avoiding scripts is an absolute requirement, I would go for the Makefile solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to ask on each TeX run whether to include the answers or not. This way you only need the TeX file and nothing else. It might get annoying to have to answer the question though.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\def\TestIncludeAnswersTrue{true}
\def\TestIncludeAnswersFalse{false}
\def\askanswers{
  \typein[\IncludeAnswers]{Include answers?
  (\TestIncludeAnswersTrue/\TestIncludeAnswersFalse)}
  \ifx\TestIncludeAnswersTrue\IncludeAnswers
    \printanswers
  \else
    \ifx\TestIncludeAnswersFalse\IncludeAnswers
    \else
      \typeout{Please answer with '\TestIncludeAnswersTrue' or
      '\TestIncludeAnswersFalse'}
      \askanswers
    \fi
  \fi
}
\askanswers


\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question What is the first sentence of \emph{Moby Dick}?
  \begin{solution}
    \emph{Call me Ishmael.}
  \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When running with overleal.com, this program fails with "Emergency stop.
<read 0> 
         
l.18 \askanswers""

Comment: @pzorba75 perhaps overleaf doesn't support `\typein`.