# specify outputfile for pdflatex

Tags: output

pdflatex provides a possibility to specify the output directory:

```
-output-directory=DIR use DIR as the directory to write files to
```

I would like to set the output file so that

`pdflatex file.tex` create a foo.pdf instead of file.pdf

Is that possible?

Comment: `pdflatex -jobname=foo file.tex` ?

Comment: setting `-jobname` did not help

Comment: But works for me.

Comment: I found out that the order is important: `pdflatex -jobname=foo file.tex` OK `pdflatex  file.tex -jobname=foo` FAIL

Comment: Cannot confirm this. For me any of  `pdflatex -jobname=foo -output-directory=bar file.tex` and `pdflatex -output-directory=bar -jobname=foo file.tex` produces `bar/foo.pdf`.

Comment: @AlexG, it is important that `file.tex` succedes all of the options.

Comment: Yes, this is what `pdflatex --help` tells.

Comment: @AlexG, will you provide an answer to this question?

Comment: More general case of [jobname - How to influence the name of the pdf file created with pdfLaTeX (from within the source code)? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the/666901#666901) .

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to the command line help (`pdflatex -help`), `pdflatex` is to be invoked as

```
pdftex [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
```

with all options preceeding the source file argument.

In addition to changing the output directory, the default output file name can be altered by modifying the internal `\jobname` register through command option `-jobname=STRING`:

```
pdflatex -output-directory=DIR -jobname=STRING FILE
```

The order of options does not matter here, but `FILE` comes last.

Comment: if you say `\jobname` is an internal register, could I modify it also inside the tex document?

Comment: @Viesturs No, `\jobname` is read only.