# Change output filename within .tex

Tags: texstudio

I'm using TexStudio. I forgot what compiler I used but from memory I took MikTex but for some reasons I'm not able to find it on my computer... 
So I looked a bit around and the proposed solution for what I'm trying to do is to put this line:

```
%& -job-name=xyz
```

to have the file name as xyz.pdf. 
Right now, this is not working for me.
Also, I'm doing cover letters and I'd like to automatically have the \companyname{xyz} as the output filename. I guess this is asking too much and just being able to change the company name from the .tex file is satisfactory for me.

Comment: I saw this thread but sadly it's not working for me.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There are several questions on this topic, but you don't say which one(s) you looked at.  Here's the most frequently cited: [How to influence the name of the pdf file created with pdfLaTeX (from within the source code)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19182/579).