# How can I change PDF output name?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, naming, jobname

#### Question 1

How can we **change the name of the generated pdf file**, *automatically* on the `main.tex` file?

#### Question 2

Is it possible not to change the generated files each time I change this name?

Comment: See user 'manu's response [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the).

Comment: No, I tried this method  `%& -job-name=myNewFileName` but it doesn't work. And just for information I'm using TeXstudio and TeX Live on Windows.