# TexStudio does not show pdf preview

Tags: texstudio

I was using TexStudio and everything was fine (each time I compiled, the preview appeared at the right side). Then, I need to change the file of the pdf generated from the `tex` code. So, I used this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139963/264440). However, everytime I compiled, the content in the preview is not updated anymore. Any way to make it work with `%& -job-name=mypdf.pdf` at the top?

Comment: AFAIK TeXstudio always expects that the `log` and the `pdf` file have the same basename like the root TeX file. Can't you use a tex file `mypdf.tex` as root, that just uses one `\input <originaltexfile>.tex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `| txs:///view-pdf "mypdf.pdf"` to your magic comment to specify which file should be shown in the pdf viewer:

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex -jobname=mypdf  % | txs:///view-pdf "mypdf.pdf"
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```