# Create two documents from one texclipse project

Tags: editors, tex-general, eclipse

We have one main LaTeX project in texclipse for our Help Documentation and that works great. However we have a folder and tex file on installation instructions of our software which we would like to also build as a document of its own. What strategy can we follow in texclipse to achieve that? We want to be able to create other documents from that main one.

Comment: I removed the [tag:latex-project] tag, which is about [The LaTeX Project](http://www.latex-project.org/) and not about project files in IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Is it related to this question: [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files)

There are a couple of solutions there, the surest of them is the `\write18` one... but it's pretty hairy one way or the other.