# How to write shell script for latex compliation?

Tags: pdftex, templates

Here's my needs.
I have a latex file or template, some content of this file(say company name) needs to be changed according to different companies. I want to write a shell script satisfying this need, help me auto compilation and generating the corresponding pdf file.

Is anyone having similar experiences before? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shell scripting rather than TeX.

Comment: Use `sed` and/or `gawk`. But this is not a TeX question and would be better asked elsewhere.

Comment: You do not need a shell script for this. There are more than one on-topic LaTeX solutions for this.

Comment: Following up on what @Fran said, you might want to look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files But yeah, as things stand, I'm voting to close as off-topic, since the question is explicitly about shell scripting.

Comment: (If you rephrase the question to ask what \*TeX-related ways you can achieve the same result as some shell script might, the powers that be may vote to reopen the question.)  Another possibility: create a `.csv` file and then use `datatool` or `csvsimple` to spit out several identical files *mutatis mutandis*.

Answer (score 2):

A childplay for the `textmerg` package. A simple example:

You have this text file called `data.dat` where every tree lines of text contain the name, surname and name company:

```
David
Smith
Tipix

Edoardo
Vinchenzo
Pizzaboom
```

And a simple template `file.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textmerg} 

\begin{document}

\Fields{\Name\Surname\Company} 

\Merge{data.dat}{ 

Dear Mr. \Name{} \Surname{},

Your company \Company{} has .... 

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip 

 }

\end{document}
```

Then, compiled as usual (`pdflatex file.tex`) the result is:

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the most rated answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document). There is a description how to inject a switch for an if clause. You could inject your names in a script somehow like this:

```
pdflatex -jobname outputname "\def\name{Hello world} \input{foo.tex}"
```

You choose output name and Hello world in your script.