# Splitting a bibliography-driven Latex document into per-page Open Document ODT files?

Tags: biblatex, compiling, tex4ht

I have already seen [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files), and I'm aware this is likely to require "external" scripting - but I just wanted to see if anyone has a straightforward approach.

With the MWE posted below, I'm trying to create an "article card" - for each of the given citations sourced from a bibliography, generate a page with the given citation, and all of the author names - one author name per line. This works fine as far as Latex to PDF is concerned; and the output is something like this (click for full res):

[image: test.png]

Now this is what I want to do - I want each of these pages as a .odt Open Document, with the same name as the citation; that is, instead of the single PDF with 4 pages -- I'd want 4 ODT documents, named according to the respective citation key, that is: `aksin.odt`, `cotton.odt`, `herrmann.odt`, `murray.odt`, for each page respectively.

I have seen [How to convert .tex into .odt? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82634/how-to-convert-tex-into-odt), and the suggestions there - but I'm not really sure, if it would be possible e.g. to call `latex test.tex` + `biber test` once, and then do one (or multiple) calls to, say `mk4ht oolatex test.tex` which would generate the per-page .odt files.

Any ideas/pointers about the most straightforward way to achieve this?

The `test.tex` code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

% based on {name:delim}, biblatex.def
% use newline as delimiter (not \par, as it indents)
\newbibmacro*{name:delimline}[1]{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
       or
       test \ifmorenames
     }
       {\newline}%{\multinamedelim}
       {\newline}}%{\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}}
    {}}

% based on {name:first-last}, biblatex.def
% simply uses the above line as delimiter
\newbibmacro*{name:first-lastline}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delimline}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{%
    \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
    \ifpunctmark{'}
      {}
      {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
  \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
  \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}

% based on [labelname], biblatex.def
\DeclareNameFormat{labelnameallline}{%
%   \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
%     \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
%   \or
%     \ifuseprefix
%       {\usebibmacro{name:first-lastline}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}% w/ firstinits
%       {\usebibmacro{name:first-lastline}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}% w/ firstinits
%   \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-lastline}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}% % without firstinits!
%   \fi
%  %\usebibmacro{name:andothers}% output all explicitly
}

% \setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{firstinits=false}%
% \csname KV@blx@opt@pre@firstinits\endcsname -> \settoggle {blx@firstinits}{#1}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeallnamesline}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  %{\printnames[first-last]{labelnameallline}}
  {%
    \makeatletter%
    % NO spaces here in iftoggle, or before endcsname!
    \typeout{IT IS: \expandafter\meaning\csname KV@blx@opt@pre@firstinits\endcsname}%
    \iftoggle{blx@firstinits}{\typeout{true}}{\typeout{false}}%
    %\setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{firstinits=false}% no influence here, if it is false already; but doesn't matter, because NameFormat labelnameallline now explicitly uses full names
    \makeatother%
    % print all names w/ \thelisttotal, regardless of other settings
    \printnames[labelnameallline][-\thelisttotal]{author}%
  }
  {}%\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\def\pageTemplate#1{%
  \section*{\centering Article Card}
  \bigskip
  \noindent The paper is:
  \bigskip

  \fullcite{#1}
  \bigskip

  \noindent The authors are:
  \bigskip

  \noindent%
  %\citeauthor{#1}
  \citeallnamesline{#1}

  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\foreach\x in {aksin,cotton,herrmann,murray}{
  \pageTemplate{\x}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find any tool which can split a `ODT` file to standalone pages, so
I think easiest way is to make a script which will create a TeX file for each card and call `oolatex` on these files. We can create one big `.bbl` file which include all records from a `bib` file and use this file for each file.

The Lua script `makecards.lua`:

```
local bibfile = arg[1]
local citekeys = arg[2]
local tplfilename = "template.tex"
print("bibfile:  "..bibfile)
print("citekeys: "..citekeys)

local main = [[
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{$bibfile}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
]]
main = main:gsub("$bibfile",bibfile)

local latex = io.popen("latex -jobname="..bibfile,"w")
latex:write(main)
latex:close()

os.execute("biber "..bibfile)
local bblfile = io.open(bibfile..".bbl","r")
local bbl = bblfile:read("*all")
bblfile:close()

local tplfile = io.open(tplfilename,"r")
local tpl = tplfile:read("*all")
tplfile:close()
tpl = tpl:gsub("$bibfile",bibfile)

for key in citekeys:gmatch("([^%,]+)") do
  print(key)
  local tpl = tpl:gsub("$bibkey",key)
  local f = io.open(key..".tex","w")
  f:write(tpl)
  f:close()
  local b = io.open(key..".bbl","w")
  b:write(bbl)
  b:close()
  os.execute("mk4ht oolatex " .. key)
end
```

as you can see, dummy TeX file is used to create a `bbl` file, which is then copied for each citekey. Also a TeX file for each `citekey` is created, using templete file, "template.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{$bibfile}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\large\centering}

% based on {name:delim}, biblatex.def
% use newline as delimiter (not \par, as it indents)
\newbibmacro*{name:delimline}[1]{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
       or
       test \ifmorenames
     }
       {\newline}%{\multinamedelim}
       {\newline}}%{\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}}
    {}}

% based on {name:first-last}, biblatex.def
% simply uses the above line as delimiter
\newbibmacro*{name:first-lastline}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delimline}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{%
    \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
    \ifpunctmark{'}
      {}
      {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
  \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
  \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}

% based on [labelname], biblatex.def
\DeclareNameFormat{labelnameallline}{%
%   \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
%     \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
%   \or
%     \ifuseprefix
%       {\usebibmacro{name:first-lastline}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}% w/ firstinits
%       {\usebibmacro{name:first-lastline}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}% w/ firstinits
%   \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-lastline}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}% % without firstinits!
%   \fi
%  %\usebibmacro{name:andothers}% output all explicitly
}

% \setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{firstinits=false}%
% \csname KV@blx@opt@pre@firstinits\endcsname -> \settoggle {blx@firstinits}{#1}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeallnamesline}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  %{\printnames[first-last]{labelnameallline}}
  {%
    \makeatletter%
    % NO spaces here in iftoggle, or before endcsname!
    \typeout{IT IS: \expandafter\meaning\csname KV@blx@opt@pre@firstinits\endcsname}%
    \iftoggle{blx@firstinits}{\typeout{true}}{\typeout{false}}%
    %\setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{firstinits=false}% no influence here, if it is false already; but doesn't matter, because NameFormat labelnameallline now explicitly uses full names
    \makeatother%
    % print all names w/ \thelisttotal, regardless of other settings
    \printnames[labelnameallline][-\thelisttotal]{author}%
  }
  {}%\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\def\pageTemplate#1{%
  \section*{Article Card}
  \bigskip
  \noindent The paper is:
  \bigskip

  \fullcite{#1}
  \bigskip

  \noindent The authors are:
  \bigskip

  \noindent%
  %\citeauthor{#1}
  \citeallnamesline{#1}

  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

  \pageTemplate{$bibkey}

\end{document}
```

I removed some unneeded packages from your sample.

It should be compiled with

```
texlua makecards.lua bibfilename "citekeys,separated,with,comma"
```

The result needs some refinements, though:

[image]

Comment: That is fantastic, @michal.h21 - I would never have thought of using Lua for the purpose, many thanks for that!

Comment: @sdaau it is just that I am most familiar with Lua and it is included in every TeX distribution, any language would work (even TeX itself, but it would be much more difficult)