# 2 PDF Outputs at once with 2 different styles

Tags: pdftex

Is it possible to export into 2 PDF Files at once? It should have the same text, but use 2 different style documents. For now I just rename the Style Documents all the time, but there must be an easier way right?

I am using a beamer class theme, but I need it one in a white background and one in a dark one. And it would be convenient to be able to export 2 pdfs at once with each style document.

I am using texlive-2015 on Kde Neon with Texmaker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files)

Comment: There is no solution in it to the problem of two outputs there with 2 styles. Please read the question before marking it always as a duplicate, thats just mean, since no one can get help then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a little trick, you can pass information to your .tex file when compiling. So all you need is some makefile that compiles the following example with

```
 pdflatex -jobname=dark  filename
 pdflatex -jobname=light filename
```

<strike>This can be done from within `texmaker` with a magic comment.</strike>

**Argh!** Apparently `texmaker`, unlike it's sibling `texstudio`, does not understand magic comments :(

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex -jobname=dark % | pdflatex -jobname=light %

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xstring}

\IfEq{\jobname}{\detokenize{dark}}{
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!50!black}
}{%
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!50!white}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    bla
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try with Texstudio. Have it also installed, just  don't use it, cause it is nearly unusable with a dark theme in KDE (The Highlighting of the Line makes everything invisible...). But if this works I am grateful.

Comment: @Severus15 The highliting colour can easily be customised.

Comment: @Severus15 Go to `preferences->Syntax Highlighting->Line highlighting->current` and click on the rectangular coloured square in the background colour column and change to whatever you want.

Comment: @Severus15 Probably you have to compile twice, try with `pdflatex -jobname=dark % | pdflatex -jobname=dark % | pdflatex -jobname=light % | pdflatex -jobname=light % | txs:///view-pdf light.pdf`

Comment: Wow thanks. Now it works. I'll accept the solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Severus15 I added a view command to my last comment, maybe useful.