# Display error messages in TeXstudio (--shell-escape)

Tags: texstudio, shell-escape, compilation-error

In order to get three output files at the same time (by one compilation) I added the option `--shell-escape` and

```
\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
\immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname_halb"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{2}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname_voll"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{3}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\expandafter\stop
\fi
```

to my preamble, but errors aren't displayed anymore now and a failing compilation process isn't being stopped. How can I achieve a normal behavior again?

**Update**

This example works and produces three different output files:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tagging}

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
\immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname_halb"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{2}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname_voll"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{3}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\expandafter\stop
\fi

\ifnum\conditionmacro>1 \usetag{halb}\fi

\ifnum\conditionmacro=3 \usetag{voll}\fi

\begin{document}

    test

    \tagged{halb}{test-halb}

    \tagged{voll}{test-voll}

\end{document}
```

This one doesn't (of course), but instead of stopping the process and displaying errors (like the normal behavior of TeXstudio), it gets stucked:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tagging}

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
\immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname_halb"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{2}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\immediate\write18{%
    pdflatex --jobname="\jobname_voll"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{3}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\expandafter\stop
\fi

\ifnum\conditionmacro>1 \usetag{halb}\fi

\ifnum\conditionmacro=3 \usetag{voll}\fi

\begin{document}

    test

    \tagged{halb}{test-halb}

    \tagged{voll}{test-voll}

    }

\end{document}
```

I would like to keep the usual behavior of TeXstudio.

Comment: the first call looks very suspicious as you are using the same output (and log file) as the main calling routine.  I'd be really wary of using `--shell-escape` as a routine usage, it is disabled by default for good reason.

Comment: No, I took it from a LaTeX expert here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5265

Comment: No that is completely different: it uses a different jobname for all the subsiduary files.

Comment: I don't understand. I just adjusted the jobnames for my purpose. I've tried it out with the original code, it has the same effect.

Comment: In my example the subsidiary names are `\jobname1`, `\jobname2` and `\jobname3`. Remark the numbers at the end.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there is written 1, 2, 3 or blabla, halb, voll! It's just about output names. The thing is: TeXstudio doesn't stop a failing process and doesn't produce an error message either. I need the numbers afterwards (conditionmacro) in order to distinguish several cases after that code block.

Comment: Improve your problem description. Your code snippet is faulty and incomplete and so can't be used to test your problem.

Comment: I've just improved it now, see above.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect txs to do here, there are 3 log files and 3 pdf files. which one do you want txs to open? to prevent the stuck issue at the very least, probably pass in `-interaction=nonstopmode` to your internal calls as well.

Comment: The last one (`\jobname_voll.log`) because it contains the other two cases, or rather the whole document (for my actual purposes). I've passed your mentioned option to my internal calls (to each of the three corresponding lines) now. Thank you! But how can I tell TeXstudio to load the right log file?

Comment: you still have the first write18 writing to `\jobname` that can not work in general.

Comment: Actually it's superfluous for the desired output, I can omit this option. But even if I give it a different name, how can I achieve that TeXstudio shows my desired log then, i.e. as if there was just `\jobname_voll` running as the only instance?