# Write part of output to a separate .pdf?

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to cause the pdf output from the `\crtlistoflabels` below to be written to a `.pdf` file separate from the main content?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:two}
$1+1=2$.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:four}
$2+2=5$.
\end{thm}

\crtlistoflabels

\end{document}
```

Obviously, I could just process the source as usual and then use a utility such as Adobe Acrobat to pull out the page(s) of the `\crtlistoflabels` output into a separate file. But I'm seeking a way to just redirect the `.pdf` output at that point in the processing.

(*Rationale:* I want that separate pdf document, containing meta-information about my source, in a separate window, for reference while I'm writing more source.)

Comment: You can't have two separate output PDFs with TeX (any flavour of it). You need to either split the PDF or run TeX twice (perhaps with LuaTeX or ConTeXt you can; I'm not sure about those).

Comment: You need to do two runs,.

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I don't understand - two runs of what how? And how does this put the list of labels, and only that, in a separate .pdf?

Comment: you need to have some \if.. conditionals in the document to make both versions, then run latex twice ("two runs")  one to make the full document then again to make the list docuemnt

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ah, understood now. Thanks.