# Multiple pdf outputs from one single .tex file

Tags: overleaf, shell-escape

The following MWE code is working perfectly in TexLive2018 but is not working in "www.overleaf.com" (an online Latex platform).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
\immediate\write18{%
    pdfLaTeX --jobname="\jobname1"
    \gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname
}%
\immediate\write18{%
    pdfLaTeX --jobname="\jobname2"
    \gdef\string\conditionmacro{2}\string\input\space\jobname
}%
\immediate\write18{%
    pdfLaTeX --jobname="\jobname3"
    \gdef\string\conditionmacro{3}\string\input\space\jobname
}%
\expandafter\stop
\fi

\begin{document}
    \ifnum\conditionmacro=1 
    Condition is 1
    \fi
    \ifnum\conditionmacro=2 
    Condition is 2
    \fi
    \ifnum\conditionmacro=3 
    Condition is 3
    \fi
    \verb|\conditionmacro| is \texttt{\meaning\conditionmacro}.
\end{document}
```

The raw log from "www.overleaf.com" is as follows:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
>   (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.8.28)  28 NOV 2019 12:59 entering
>   extended mode  \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
>   **main.tex (/compile/main.tex LaTeX2e <2018-12-01> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>   Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo File:
>   size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option) )
>   \c@part=\count80 \c@section=\count81 \c@subsection=\count82
>   \c@subsubsection=\count83 \c@paragraph=\count84
>   \c@subparagraph=\count85 \c@figure=\count86 \c@table=\count87
>   \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
>   \bibindent=\dimen102 ) runsystem(pdfLaTeX --jobname="output1" \gdef
>   \conditionmacro{1}\input output).. .executed.
>
> runsystem(pdfLaTeX --jobname="output2" \gdef \conditionmacro{2}\input
>   output).. .executed.
>
> runsystem(pdfLaTeX --jobname="output3" \gdef \conditionmacro{3}\input
>   output).. .executed.
>
> )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  198 strings out of
>   492616  2143 string characters out of 6128979  59595 words of memory
>   out of 5000000  4200 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
>   3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000  1141
>   hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  23i,1n,17p,112b,36s stack
>   positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>
> No pages of output. PDF statistics:  0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max.
>   8388607)  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)  1 words of
>   extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

CAN SOMEBODY PLEASE HELP ME??

Comment: The code needs `--shell-escape` and imho overleaf doesn't allow this.

Comment: Hello! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Note that what Ulrike mentions is basically right; we have to apply security restrictions, and `--shell-escape` conveys some security threats. I'll though double-check what exactly is going on here, and then eventually answer you in more detail.

Comment: So I found out the process it yet more complicated; the issue is not in `shell-escape` restriction, but in `\jobname` changes. See the answer.

Comment: (this question is specific to overleaf. For the general question see [compiling - Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files/))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Tom from the Overleaf Support Team writing.)

Please note that due to the Overleaf setup, while you can run `pdflatex` within `\immediate\write18` or `\ShellEsc`, you have to be careful about file names. Namely the `\jobname` is set to `output`, but the main file keeps it original name (`main.tex` in the example below).

So relying on `\input\jobname` is really impossible, and I'd avoid any usage of `\jobname`. Also note that `pdflatex` should be all lowercase on *nix machines. Last but not least, the only way to access the files generated by the `shell-escape` runs is via **Logs and output files** (right of **Recompile**) > **Other logs & files**. There you have all the `test?.pdf`, `test?.aux` and `test?.log` files.

Minimal example (to be called `main.tex` in Overleaf to make this work):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=5pt]{geometry}

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
\gdef\conditionmacro{0}
\immediate\write18{
    pdflatex --jobname="test1" "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space main"
}
\immediate\write18{
    pdflatex --jobname="test2" "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{2}\string\input\space main"
}
\immediate\write18{
    pdflatex --jobname="test3" "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{3}\string\input\space main"
}
\fi

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \centering\fontsize{40}{45}\bfseries
    JOBNAME = \jobname\par
    \ifcase\conditionmacro\relax
        % = 0
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=9cm]{test1.pdf}}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=9cm]{test2.pdf}}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=9cm]{test3.pdf}}
    \or
        % = 1
        Condition is 1
    \or
        % = 2
        Condition is 2
    \or
        % = 3
        Condition is 3
    \fi
%    \verb|\conditionmacro| is \texttt{\meaning\conditionmacro}.
\end{document}
```