# Generate two files with different class options with package shellesc

Tags: luatex, shell-escape

I want to generate multiple pdf files with different font sizes. I referred to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5265/174620) solution, and formed the following code.

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\ShellEscape{%
  lualatex --jobname="\jobname-8pt"
  "\PassOptionsToClass{8pt}{article}"
}%
\ShellEscape{%
  lualatex --jobname="\jobname-12pt"
  "\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{article}"
}%
\expandafter\stop

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

It doesn't work with the `-shell-escape` flag on the terminal. What is the correct way of coding this? What is the purpose of `\gdef\string` and `\string\input\space\jobname` in the original answer?

Comment: The \input is there as you need to input the file again. The \string to prevent that commands are executed too early.

Comment: So will this `\gdef\string\PassOptionsToClass{8pt}{article}\string\input\space\jobname` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to input the document again. The `\string` commands are used in order to avoid TeX expanding the commands, which would produce rubbish in the command line passed by `\ShellEsc`.

You also need a conditional to skip over the `\ShellEsc` part when doing the real typesetting.

I changed `article` into `amsart`, because there is no `8pt` option for the former.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{shellesc}

\ifdefined\dotypesetting\else
  \edef\typesettingcommand#1{%
    lualatex --jobname='\jobname-#1'
    '\gdef\string\dotypesetting{}% the \else part will be skipped
     \string\PassOptionsToClass{#1}{amsart}% pass the option
     \string\input{\jobname}'% input the document
  }
  \ShellEscape{\typesettingcommand{8pt}}% do the first run
  \ShellEscape{\typesettingcommand{12pt}}% do the second run
  \expandafter\stop
\fi

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and the code! This worked :)