# How to write the output in multiple pdf files

Tags: macros, output, write-file

Suppose that I want to split the output of my LaTeX document in several .pdf files.
Is there something like:

```
\fromnowwritetofile{foo.pdf}

some part of my document

\fromnowritetofile{foo2.pdf}

some other part

\fromnowwriteagaintofile{foo.pdf} %I don't know it this is asking too much.
```

Comment: See if that gets you started: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files

Comment: You'd have to start a new page, write the current absolute page number to an auxiliary file, create a script that reads in that auxiliary file and splits your output pdf into several files based on that auxiliary file's contents. LaTeX alone can't open multiple output files, only one PDF is supported.