# Physical Review Letters supporting information separate PDF

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, cross-referencing, revtex

I am preparing a paper for submission to Physical Review Letters, and the journal requires that the main text and supplementary information be separated into two PDFs. I currently have links between the main text and the supplementary information using the `hyperref` package; I additionally have citations in the appendix which are printed in the bibliography section in the main text. Ideally, I would like to be able to take my LaTeX file and output two separate PDF documents which preserve the bibliography, figure, section, and equation references. It is not necessary to be able to click on links and open the reference in the other file; I just need the appropriate text to be displayed. Is this possible? Will PRL accept a .tex file that outputs a single PDF, but the PDFs I submit are manually separated using a PDF editor like Adobe Acrobat?

I would appreciate any help from anyone who has experience with this. Thank you!

Comment: Common problem.  PS this tool is relevant to anyone preparing PRL submission https://github.com/matteoacrossi/texprlcount

Comment: One of the questions you asked is not answerable by this forum. "Will PRL accept X" is only answerable by the editor(s) at PRL. The other question on "Is this possible?" I assume is asking about whether it is possible to make one TeX document output multiple PDF files. For that see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5228/119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PRL content guidelines](https://journals.aps.org/prl/authors#content) say

> Cite the manuscript’s Supplemental Material in the reference list as follows:
>
> See Supplemental Material at [URL will be inserted by publisher] for [give brief description of material].

From this I understand that they don't want you to put hyperlinks between the main document and the Supplemental Material. Consider also this:

> In a longer format manuscript, it may be best to present additional material as an appendix to the main article, rather than as Supplemental Material.