# Writing Notes, want my equations organized at the end of document

Tags: equations

I'm writing up my textbook notes in LateX. As I am writing paragraphs, I am inserting equations while I'm writing.

I want to somehow display all of my numbered equations at the end of my document in the same order that they were numbered.  Is there a way to easily do this in LaTex with an unknown command that I might not know???

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  It might be helpful to know how you are producing your document as the solutions might depend on that.

Comment: You may want to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67550/write-content-of-box-to-a-file

Answer (score 8):

This solution borrows very heavily from David Carlisle's solution to [Write content of box to a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67550/write-content-of-box-to-a-file)

The idea is to renew the `equation` environment so that it not only outputs to the page, but its contents are also written to a `vbox` that is outputted at the end of the document.

You can extend the idea easily to other environments (such as `align`, for example).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% to store the contents of a SINGLE equation
\newsavebox{\mybox}

% to store the contents of ALL of the equations
\newbox\savedqns
\setbox\savedqns\vbox{}

% we're going to renew the equation environment
% using the original definition as a base
\let\oldeqn\equation
\let\oldendeqn\endequation

% renew the equation environment
\renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    \oldeqn%\begin{equation*}
}
{%
  \oldendeqn%\end{equation*}
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  % output the box to the page
  \vspace{\abovedisplayskip}%
  \noindent\usebox{\mybox}%
  \vspace{\belowdisplayskip}%
  % save the equations for later
  \global\setbox\savedqns\vbox{%
  \unvbox\savedqns
  \bigskip
  \filbreak
  \noindent\usebox{\mybox}}
  }


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  y=mx+b
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
  y=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation*}
  y=mx+b
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Copied equations}
\unvbox\savedqns

\end{document}
```