# How to store to-be-credited contributors for acknowledgment later in the appendix

Tags: macros, token-lists, collect

In my thesis, I create numerous drawings using TikZ. In these drawings, I include pictures (e.g. icons of [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/)) using Creative Commons licenses. I thus have to acknowledge their authors.

Since my drawings can include up to a dozen of pictures, I cannot credit respective authors in the caption. I thus want to acknowledge them in a specific section in the appendix.

**Question:** How to conveniently store contributors name at the time I'm drawing the TikZ picture, to use them later in the appendix?

I'm expecting following behaviors:

- *Contributors name storage*: use a macro that stores both Author and Picture Name - e.g. `\mymacro{John Doe}{Sunrise}`. If possible, I could use this macro several time in a picture (e.g. each time I load the icon) without multiple crediting author.
- *Acknowledgment generating*: I would use a macro like `\printacknowledgement` and this would generate following list:

  > *Figure 1*: 'Sunrise' by John Doe, 'Curry wurst' by Erika Mustermann.
  >   *Figure 3*: 'Sunrise' and 'Sunset' by John Doe.

Note that: *Figure 2* is not displayed because no contributor has to be credited; in *Figure 3*, it should print «*'Sunrise' and 'Sunset' by John Doe*» and not «*'Sunrise' by John Doe, 'Sunset' by John Doe*»

---

<sub>**N.B.**: I do acknowledge this looks like a do-it-for-me question. I expressed requirements specification because I don't know how to achieve this, even what package I should look for. But I'm of course willing to contribute to solution development/to develop it by myself if one tells me which package/macro I should study.

Requirements are of course ideal. I'd be also happy with bulkier solutions as `\mymacro{Figure number}{John Doe}{Sunrise}` and «*'Sunrise' by John Doe, 'Sunset' by John Doe*» being printed.

**Edit**: the [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package mentioned in [How to collect text for later usage in appendix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76471/64454) does not seems to enable to append a name at the end of the list.</sub>

Comment: For figure 3, would you have `\mymacro{John Doe}{Sunrise}\mymacro{John Doe}{Sunset}`?  It may be slightly easier if you're willing to type `\mymacro{Sunrise and Sunset by John Doe}` (i.e., manually type out the acknowledgement, but leave it to TeX to put it in the right location).

Comment: @Teepeemm I would have `\mymacro{John Doe}{Sunrise}\mymacro{John Doe}{Sunset}` (and might even have several `\mymacro{John Doe}{Sunrise}`): the point would be to credit authors at the time of loading the picture, so I'm sure I forget no one... but also that credits are updated if I eventually remove one picture.

Comment: Sorry, I meant within a single figure.  I'm assuming you wouldn't repeat the same macro with the same arguments within a figure.  Would you be willing to do the manual editing?  Or would the contents of Figure 3 be changing, so that you'd need to have separate macro calls?

Comment: @Teepeemm Separate macro calls would be better (and the must would be to be able to use `\mymacro{John Doe}{Sunrise}` several times *within the same picture* - i.e. each time I load the Sunrise icon)

Comment: Short outline: I'd try to have TeX maintain a database. Either via the commands of the **datatool** package for adding entries/rows to existing databases or by having TeX write an external CSV file containing a database via `\addtocontents`/`\addcontentsline` and a patched variant of the `\@starttoc`-macro . I would use the **datatool** package for sorting out and formatting and printing the single database entries entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I try to implement the syntax requested by the OP.  `\mymacro{Author}{Title}` should be added inside each particular `figure` environment, as needed, and `\printacknowledgement` is to be invoked at the end.

The logic is set up to handle figures with one or more acknowledgements, and to handle author repitition *if the repetitions within a given figure appear adjacently in the `\mymacro` invocations.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,ifthen}
\newcounter{myack}
\newcounter{ackx}
\newcommand\mymacro[2]{%e.g. \mymacro{Erika Mustermann}{Curry wurst}
    \stepcounter{myack}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname ack\themyack icon\endcsname{#2}% defines e.g. \ack2icon = Curry wurst
    \expandafter\xdef\csname ack\themyack auth\endcsname{#1}% defines e.g. \ack2auth = Erika Mustermann
    \expandafter\xdef\csname ack\themyack fig\endcsname{\thefigure}% defines e.g. \ack2fig = I1
}
\def\priorfig{0}
\def\isnewfig{T}
\newcommand\printacknowledgement{%
    \section*{Acknowledgement}
        \whiledo{\value{ackx}<\value{myack}}{%                                  while nb of acknowledgment printed < nb of acknowledgment defined
        \stepcounter{ackx}%                                                          number of acknowledgment printed += 1
        \ifthenelse{
            \equal{\csname ack\theackx fig\endcsname}{\priorfig}
        }{%                                                                       if acknowledgment is about same fig as the previous one
            \def\isnewfig{F}%                                                            then \isnewfig = F
        }{%                                                                       else
            \def\isnewfig{T}%                                                            isnewfig = T (this is a new figure)
            \ifthenelse{%                                                                and thus print a dot (. - except for the very first figure)
                \equal{\priorfig}{0}%
            }{%
                %
            }{%
                .%
            }%
            \par%                                                                        and create a new paragraph
        }%
        %
        \if T\isnewfig%                                                                  ... and 
            \noindent\textit{Figure \csname ack\theackx fig\endcsname:} %                start a new line with 'Figure <name of the figure>: '
        \fi%
        \if T\isnewfig%
            %
        \else%                                                                        if its not a new figure
            \if T\showauth\relax%
                , %                                                                       add ', ' only if we're crediting a new author.
            \fi%
        \fi%
        \ifthenelse{%                                                                 
            \equal{\csname ack\theackx fig\endcsname}{\csname ack\the\numexpr\theackx+1\relax fig\endcsname}%
        }{%                                                                           if this credit and the next one are from the same picture
            \ifthenelse{%
                \equal{\csname ack\theackx auth\endcsname}{\csname ack\the\numexpr\theackx+1\relax auth\endcsname}%
            }{%                                                                           
                \def\showauth{F}%                                                         \showauth = F: don't print author name right now cuz we need to add more icone names before
            }{%
                \def\showauth{T}%                                                         else \showauth = T (need to credit author name now)
            }%
        }{%
            \def\showauth{T}%                                                         else \showauth = T (need to credit author name now)
        }%
        `\csname ack\theackx icon\endcsname' %                                        print '<Icon's name> '
        \if T\showauth%
            by \csname ack\theackx auth\endcsname%                                    print 'by <Author name>' if we've to print author name, 
        \else%
            and %                                                                     else print 'and ' (waiting for next icon's name)
        \fi
        %
        \edef\priorfig{\csname ack\theackx fig\endcsname}%                            redefine Fig. nb and author of prior acknowledment
        \edef\priorauth{\csname ack\theackx auth\endcsname}%
    }.%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image}
        \caption{blah blah}%
        \mymacro{John Doe}{Sunrise}%
        \mymacro{Erika Mustermann}{Curry wurst}%
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image}
        \caption{blah blah}%
        \mymacro{John Doe}{Sunrise}%
        \mymacro{John Doe}{Sunset}%
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image}
        \caption{blah blah}%
        \mymacro{John Doe}{Sunrise}%
    \end{figure}
    \printacknowledgement
\end{document}
```

[image]

One less than ideal behavior that could be remedied with extra work is that if a given figure has 3 (or more) icons from a given author, the acknowledgement will appear as `'Sunrise' and 'Sunset' and 'Moonglow' by John Doe`, rather than as `'Sunrise', 'Sunset', and 'Moonglow' by John Doe`

Comment: Wow! MWE works like a charm, just need to figure out why I get a `! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.` in my real case scenario (it's a good motivation to study LaTeX "dirty internals"). Anyway, many thanks!

Comment: Raised error comes from my figure's numbering. Indeed, I redefined it as following in a `scrbook` document: `\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithout{figure}{chapter} \counterwithin{figure}{part} \renewcommand\thefigure{\thepart.\arabic{figure}}`. I'll try to work on your solution.

Comment: Steven: I've felt free to edit your answer as following: I've replaced the `\ifnum` conditional testings with `\ifthenelse{\equal{...` ones, in order to handle the case where `\thefigure` is not an integer (e.g. within `scrbook` documents, `\thefigure` is formated as `<chap. nb>.<img nb>`). I've also added verbose comments and reshaped the structure, so that script structure appear obvious. (Writing a new answer did not appear necessary since change are minor compared to the work you did.)

Comment: @ebo Since your edits were, I think, somewhat significant (more than just a typo), a better approach in the future, in such a case, would be to add your revised code as an addendum to my answer, while leaving my original code in place, for comparison.

Comment: Steven: Thank you for your feedback. I hope I did not unintentionally offend you. My primary intention was only to increment a little on your work and keep your answer concise. But I do can understand your point, and seeing a code that is not yours in your answer might indeed make you feel uncomfortable. My apologies.

Comment: @ebo it is no problem at all.  Just a suggestion for future interactions with the site.

Answer (score 5):

I know this sounds like magic, but, hey, it works!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addcredit}{mm}
 {
  \ebo_addcredit:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printcredits}{}
 {
  \ebo_printcredits:
 }

\prop_new:N \g_ebo_credit_names_prop
\seq_new:N \g_ebo_credit_list_seq
\seq_new:N \l__ebo_credit_item_seq
\clist_new:N \l__ebo_credit_list_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ebo_addcredit:nn
 {
  \prop_if_exist:cF { g_ebo_credit_ \thefigure _prop }
   {
    % create a property list and register it
    \prop_new:c { g_ebo_credit_ \thefigure _prop }
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_ebo_credit_list_seq { \thefigure }
   }
  \prop_if_in:cnTF { g_ebo_credit_ \thefigure _prop } { #1 }
   { % there's already credit for #1
     \prop_gput:cnx { g_ebo_credit_ \thefigure _prop }
      { #1 }
      { \prop_item:cn { g_ebo_credit_ \thefigure _prop } { #1 } , \exp_not:n { { `#2' } } }
   }
   { % no credit for #1
     \prop_gput:cnn { g_ebo_credit_ \thefigure _prop }
      { #1 }
      { { `#2' } }
   }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_ebo_credit_names_prop { #1 } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ebo_printcredits:
 {
  \section{Acknowledgments}
  \begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=*]
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_ebo_credit_list_seq
   {
    \item[\textit{Figure~##1}:] \__ebo_credit_print:n { ##1 }.
   }
  \end{itemize}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ebo_credit_print:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__ebo_credit_item_seq
  \prop_map_inline:cn { g_ebo_credit_ #1 _prop }
   {% ##1 is the author, ##2 is the list of credits
    \clist_set:Nn \l__ebo_credit_list_clist { ##2 }
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__ebo_credit_item_seq
     {
      \clist_use:Nnnn \l__ebo_credit_list_clist { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and~ }~by~
      \prop_item:Nn \g_ebo_credit_names_prop { ##1 }
     }
   }
   \seq_use:Nn \l__ebo_credit_item_seq { ;~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{First figure}
\addcredit{John Doe}{Sunrise}
\addcredit{Erika Musterman}{Curry Wurst}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{Third figure}
\addcredit{John Doe}{Sunrise}
\addcredit{John Doe}{Sunset}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{Fourth figure}
\addcredit{\'Accented Aüthor}{Dawn}
\addcredit{John Doe}{Sunset}
\addcredit{John Doe}{Sunrise}
\addcredit{John Doe}{Evening}
\end{figure}

\printcredits

\end{document}
```

The `\addcredit` macro adds material to a property list linked to the figure number (so it *must* appear after `\caption`).

If the same author appears further in the same `figure`, the corresponding property is added the new title. The figure number is stored sequentially, so we can map through those that have `\addcredit` commands.

It is your responsibility that the author's name is the same in all `\addcredit` commands for the same figure.

The `\printcredits` command maps the sequence of figures with credits; for each one of them, the corresponding property list is mapped to form the required text: first the list of contributions, then the author name. If there are two contributions, they're separated by “and”; if more, there will be a comma, between two of them, except the last with “, and”. Remove the comma in the code, if you don't like the Oxford comma.

Use `\addcredit` for the same author in one `figure` one after the other, or the final order would be unpredictable.

[image]

Comment: Wouaou. Out of curiosity: do you have a program to produce all this magic, or do you append `ebo` to all variables names by hand?

Comment: @Clément The program is called `egregbrains`, I'll try getting it on GitHub one day.