# Sections (paragraphs) ordered different than in code

Tags: best-practices, exercises

I need to write a task assignment (a paragraph ordered by `enumerate`) and attach a solution (possibly using `hyperref` technique). That's clear. But now I want the task solution to be placed at the end of the document in PDF but next to the assignment in the code.

What would be the best option to do so?

**Example:**

```
\begin{document}

\section{Tasks}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{Newton} How many apples fell on Newton's head?
    %Here should be a code: How the hell should I know?
  \item \label{Archimedes} How loud screamed Archimedes "Heureka"?
    %Here should be a code: How the hell should I know?
\end{enumerate}

\section{Solutions}

%Here should be an automatically created list of previously commented content.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The typical technique that is used to achieve this is to write the solutions to an auxiliary file, which is subsequently `\input` at the appropriate point.  Knuth did so for the answers to the exercises in _The TeXbook_, which are written immediately after the exercises they refer to in the source code, but are printed all together at the end of the book.

Comment: [exercise package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exercise?lang=en)?

Comment: You can have a look at the [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package mentioned in [How to collect text for later usage in appendix?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76471/how-to-collect-text-for-later-usage-in-appendix)