# List of all equations in the entire document

Tags: beamer, equations

I am trying to put all the equations of my presentation made with Beamer into a single table to summarize them. They are however in various frames within `\align` environments. How can I  achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `collect*` environment from the [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package; a simple example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{equations}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame with an equation}
\begin{collect*}{equations}{}{}{}{}
\begin{align*}
a &= b \\
&=c.  
\end{align*}
\end{collect*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Another frame with an equation}
\begin{collect*}{equations}{}{}{}{}
\begin{align*}
x &= y \\
&=z.  
\end{align*}
\end{collect*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Equations}
\includecollection{equations}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will this work for numbered equations in an align environment as well?

Comment: @user17947 some work will have to be done for the correct display of the counters.

Comment: \notag \vskip -1.5em?

Comment: @user17947 so you want to suppress the numbering in the final list?

Comment: no. I would like to retain it.  There is a problem with allowframebreaks option when I include the collection as a list of equations in the end inside the last frame. The equations are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that borrows from [Write content of box to a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67550/write-content-of-box-to-a-file)

I've used the [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox) to wrap the `align` and `equation` environment with

```
% surround the align environment with
%   \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
%       \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
% 
%       CONTENT
%       
%       \end{minipage}
%   \end{lrbox}
```

which saves the content to the box `\mybox`; the content is of course outputted to the screen, but it is also saved for use later on in the box `\savedeqns`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% to store the contents of a SINGLE equation
\newsavebox{\mybox}

% to store the contents of ALL of the equations
\newbox\savedqns
\setbox\savedqns\vbox{}

% surround the align environment with
%   \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
%       \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
% 
%       CONTENT
%       
%       \end{minipage}
%   \end{lrbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{align}{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{align}{%
        \end{minipage}%
        \end{lrbox}%
        \vspace{\abovedisplayskip}%
        \noindent\usebox{\mybox}%
       % save the equations for later
         \global\setbox\savedqns\vbox{%
           \unvbox\savedqns
             \bigskip
               \filbreak
                 \noindent\usebox{\mybox}}%
        }

% do the same for the equation environment
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{equation}{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{%
        \end{minipage}%
        \end{lrbox}%
        \vspace{\abovedisplayskip}%
        \noindent\usebox{\mybox}%
       % save the equations for later
         \global\setbox\savedqns\vbox{%
           \unvbox\savedqns
             \bigskip
               \filbreak
                 \noindent\usebox{\mybox}}%
        }


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{An align environment...}
\begin{align}
  y&=x^2+2\\
  &=2+x^2
\end{align}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{An equation environment...}
\begin{equation}
  y=mx+b
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{My very important equations- SUMMARY}
\unvbox\savedqns
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```