# LaTeX - Insert thumbnail with link to fullsize image contained in appendix

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing, links

What is the best way to include a small thumbnail image which links to the fullsize image which should be contained in the appendix?

Ideally it would be nice to have a macro which created a thumbnail inline and also automatically added a larger image to the appendices. Does this exist?

-- Edit --

Issue with subfigure.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
    \thumbnailandappendix{images/iPadMyPdfs} 
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
    \thumbnailandappendix{images/iPadMyPdfsPort} 
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Main Tab}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Output]

Packages used

```
\usepackage{array} %% so can bold columns in a latex table
\usepackage{float} %% used to help position images exactly where typed
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `hyperref` package's commands

```
\hyperlink{<name of link>}{<text or image>}
```

and

```
 \hypertarget{<name of link>}{<text or image>}
```

It defines the command `\thumbnailandappendix` which takes one argument- the name of the image. This command

- outputs the thumbnail to the page
- saves a bigger version of the thumbnail in a `vbox` to be used later in the appendix
- uses a counter `thumbnail` to keep the hyperlinks unique

The clever bit comes from [David Carlisle's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) answer to [Write content of box to a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67550/write-content-of-box-to-a-file)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[left]{showlabels}
%\showlabels{hypertarget}
%\showlabels{hyperlink}

% set up a counter for links
\newcounter{thumbnail}

% to store the images for later
\newbox\savedimgs
\setbox\savedimgs\vbox{}

% thumbnail and appendix command
\newcommand{\thumbnailandappendix}[1]{%
  % #1: name of image
  \refstepcounter{thumbnail}
  % input thumbnail version
  \hyperlink{big\thethumbnail}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{#1}}
  % save the big version for later
  \global\setbox\savedimgs\vbox{%
  \unvbox\savedimgs
  \bigskip
  \filbreak
  \noindent
  \hypertarget{big\thethumbnail}{}

  \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{#1}}
  }


\begin{document}

\thumbnailandappendix{Tux}

\thumbnailandappendix{babbytux}

\clearpage

\appendix

\section{Full-size image}

\unvbox\savedimgs

\end{document}
```

The `showlabels` package is especially useful during debugging.

The solution can be made to link the 'big' images back the thumbnails, however, *this only makes sense if the thumbnail is used once*

```
% thumbnail and appendix command
\newcommand{\thumbnailandappendix}[1]{%
  % #1: name of image
  \refstepcounter{thumbnail}
  % set up hypertarget before the thumbnail
  \hypertarget{small\thethumbnail}{}

  % input thumbnail version
  \hyperlink{big\thethumbnail}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{#1}}
  % save the big version for later
  \global\setbox\savedimgs\vbox{%
  \unvbox\savedimgs
  \bigskip
  \filbreak
  \noindent
  \hypertarget{big\thethumbnail}{}

  \hyperlink{small\thethumbnail}{\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{#1}}}
  }
```

If the thumbnail is used more than once, then the 'big' image will link back to the most recent thumbnail.

Note: the blank lines are intentional, and important in this `macro`.

You can use this command in the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` as expected; make sure to load `subcaption` before `hyperref`

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

and then you can use (for example)

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \thumbnailandappendix{Tux}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \thumbnailandappendix{Tux}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: How would I go about linking the big image back to the small one? That would be a nice bonus.

Comment: @bencallis you're welcome! see the update :)

Comment: Great!

One more thing I have previously used subfigure to position two figures side by side. Unfortunately using thumbnailandappendix in place of includegraphics does not seem to work there. 
"Something's wrong -- perhaps a missing \item"

Comment: @bencallis it works fine for me I have updated my answer with details

Comment: Strange. I have modified my question to show the figure i'm using.

Comment: I have managed to get thumbnailandappendix working nicely with subfigure. However, the image in the appendix is half the usual size which I guess may be to do with using {.5\textwidth}. Any ideas?