# Show limits/borders of paragraph

Tags: xetex

Is there a way to show/print the border of a paragraph to see what spacing it has before and after?

Comment: You could wrap each paragraphs into \fbox{ } - es ... But a safer way is to pick a LaTeX reference (e.g.: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths) and print the interesting lengths, like \the\baslineskip, \the\parskip etc. You may also want to use package geometry, which can show you the page-geometry (see manula for options).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2083/47927

Comment: Using `\everypar` one can easily detect the start of a paragraph, but not the end (unless you count the start of the next paragraph).  For a specific paragraph, I would add `\tikzmark`s before and fter and draw a box with TikZ  [remember picture, overlay].  Tikzpagenodes will give you the left and right edges.

Answer (score 7):

You could make use of the [`lua-visual-debug` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug) maybe (which requires typesetting with LuaTeX obviously):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\usepackage[skip=12pt, indent=30pt, parfill=50pt]{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\bigskip

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The tiny ticks to the left show where the box of the upper paragraph box ends and the lower starts (highlighted in red; sorry for the overly large pictures, but the ticks would not be visible otherwise).

This shows where the boxes of the first two paragraphs "meet":

[image]

This shows the `\bigskip` between the second and the third paragraph:

[image]

Comment: Is there something similar for XeTeX?

Comment: @wolfrevo Sadly, I currently don't know about a XeTeX solution. Maybe you could do something using `tikzmarks` or similar, so that you place anchors which you can later access ...